# Quais são os tipos de dados apropriados para colunas como endereço, e-mail, telefone e celular, para base de dados SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, modelagem, tipagem

Que tipo de dados são recomendados para criar os seguintes campos:

- endereço
- e-mail
- número de celular/telefone

Comment: MySQL - VARCHAR(size), SQLServer - nvarchar

Comment: Yuran, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow! A sua pergunta é poco clara, pode explicar melhor o que você procura saber?

Comment: normalmente varchar, mesmo o campo telefone podendo conter apenas números, salvar como texto garante que você não vai perder nenhum zero no inicio do numero, por exemplo.

Answer (score 26):

Para os campos endereço, e-mail e telefone/celular eu recomendo utilizar VARCHAR por ele possuir um tamanho variável e salvar corretamente os dados.

## Porque VARCHAR e não CHAR?

[VARCHAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) possui um tamanho variável de acordo com o registro contido nele.

Exemplo: Vou inserir a palavra "Yuran" que contém **5** caracteres em uma coluna VARCHAR(20) e o mesmo registro em outra coluna que é CHAR(20)

Na coluna VARCHAR vai ser utilizado apenas **5** caracteres dos 20, o tamanho daquele registro vai ser igual ao de um **CHAR(5)**.

Na coluna CHAR vai ser utilizado todos os 20 caracteres independente do tamanho do registro ficando com **CHAR(20)** e pesando mais no banco.

## Nunca utilize tipo numérico para salvar dados como telefone/celular

Vamos supor que você quer salvar o número "0800 800 8000" no banco, o que vai acontecer?

- Dependendo do tipo numérico vai ultrapassar o tamanho limite e com isso não vai conseguir salvar no banco os dados.
- Você vai perder todos "0" a esquerda do número e com isso você perde a integridade dos dados.

Comment: +1 E só pra citar outro exemplo, telefone pode ser algo assim também: `+55 (11) 9999-9999`

Comment: +1 por ter citado números do tipo 0800. Se há chance de 0800 e 0300 ser armazenado, é mais complicado tratar de exibir ele mais tarde.

Answer (score 11):

Um padrão que eu costumo usar é o listado abaixo. [Ele pode ser visto no meu site](http://www.fititnt.org/off/tipos-de-campos-e-exemplos-de-valores-empresas-em-sistemas-cnpj-cep.html).

Em alguns casos eu listei mais de um exemplo. Os tipos e os tamanhos são para MySQL/MariaDB.

No caso de valores que contém numeros e caracteres diversos, é necessário ter certo cuidado, principalmente se o padrão muda muito. Atender telefones fixos e celulares, como os de São Paulo que tem 9 digitos, é possível validar na hora de entrar no sistema e uma boa mascara poderá devolver ao formato original, porém a coisa vai ficar complicada se seu sistema tem que suportar também numeros internacionais e números regionais do Brasil. Nestes casos, se não quiser se encomodar, use VARCHAR mesmo, mas nos meus exemplos abaixo eu em algumas aplicações converti telefones nacionais para BIGINT e não tive problemas.

Valores numéricos mais padrões, como CEP e CPF, certamente recomendo armazenar como numérico. Marque na colula como 'ZEROFILL' que ele colocará zeros para preencher os valores iniciais.

- **Razão Social** VARCHAR(255)
- **Nome Fantasia** VARCHAR(255)
- **CNPJ** BIGINT(14), VARCHAR(18)
- **Data de Fundação** DATE
- **Email** VARCHAR(100)
- **Website** VARCHAR(100)
- **Telefone** BIGINT(14) (Já considera números de 9 dígitos). Na dúvida, use VARCHAR
- **Celular** BIGINT(14) (Já considera números de 9 dígitos) Na dúvida, use VARCHAR
- **Responsável** VARCHAR(255), VARCHAR(100)
- **Endereço** VARCHAR(150)
- **Endereço, número** VARCHAR(20) (lembre-se: "números" podem conter outros caracteres)
- **Bairro** VARCHAR(50)
- **Cidade** VARCHAR(50)
- **UF** CHAR(2), TINYINT(2) (uso de números se relacionado a outra tabela)
- **CEP** INT(8), VARCHAR(10)
- **Descrição** TEXT

Repare que com exceção de UF, sempre uso VARCHAR, porém limito o máximo a um valor razoável de ser encontrado. Por exemplo, não existe nenhuma cidade nem bairro no Brasil com mais de 50 caracteres, ou se tem, é alguma bem desconhecida e com uns 60.

### Snippets para formatar resultado numérico de determinados campos (PHP)

A formatação do telefone e celular é mais complicada porque ela não prevê números internacionais nem números 0800 o 0300. As demais já foram testadas e funcionam bem.

Colo aqui porque quem está perguntando esse tipo de questão certamente vai acabar procurando isso mais tarde.

```
/**
 * QSES component helper.
 *
 * @package  Alligo.Joomla
 * @since    1.6
 */
class AlgFilter {

    /**
     * Remove valores não numericos (inclusive , e .)
     *
     * @param   string  $input  Valor de entrada
     * @return  int
     */
    public static function getNumbers($input)
    {
        return preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $input);
    }

    /**
     * Formata 90050123 em 90.050-123
     *
     * @param   int    $numero  Numero a ser formatado
     * @return  string
     */
    public static function formatoCep($input)
    {
        return preg_replace('/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})$/', '\\1.\\2-\\3', $input);
    }

    /**
     * Formata 90050123 em 90.050-123
     *
     * @param   int    $numero  Numero a ser formatado
     * @return  string
     */
    public static function formatoCpf($input)
    {
        return preg_replace('/^(\d{1,3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})$/', '${1}.${2}.${3}-${4}', $input);
    }

    /**
     * Formata CNPJ
     *
     * @param   int    $numero  Numero a ser formatado
     * @return  string
     */
    public static function formatoCnpj($input)
    {
        return preg_replace("/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{2})$/", "\\1.\\2.\\3/\\4-\\5", $input);
    }

    /**
     * Formata 1234567890 em (12) 3456-7890
     *
     * @param   int    $numero  Numero a ser formatado
     * @return  string
     */
    public static function formatoTelefone($numero)
    {
        return preg_replace('/(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d*)/', '($1) $2-$3', $numero);
    }

}
```

Comment: _"números" podem conter outros caracteres_ - Fatão. Em Bauru/SP os endereços, por exemplo da prefeitura, têm números como 1-59, onde 1 seria algo como o número da quadra/quarteirão.

Answer (score 6):

Se você não vai fazer contas com os números (somar, multiplicar, etc), não tem muito por que usar tipos numéricos.

Use `CHAR` ou `VARCHAR`, conforme apropriado.

Answer (score 5):

Qual é o objetivo dessas informações?

Informar um dado para descrever uma característica do objeto em questão na tabela, certo?

Bem, para endereço de e-mail temos a possibilidade de usar letras, números e até símbolos. Uma coluna do tipo texto se faz necessária. Fica só a dúvida se um `CHAR` ou `VARCHAR` deve ser usado. Como estes dados tem tamanho variável com ampla margem de diferença o `CHAR` faz pouco ou nenhum sentido, até porque no MySQL ele não é tão otimizado e pode ter desempenho ligeiramente pior. Não tem nem o que pensar.

Não se preocupe muito com o tamanho, coloque algo grande.

Não se acanhe em colocar 255 ou mais para o endereço, por exemplo, já que o espaço não usado não será desperdiçado. Pode por algo menor se tiver certeza que não poderá ser maior que determinado tamanho.

No caso de e-mail, de acordo com a [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822), o endereço básico, chamado de local, pode ter 64 caracteres, mais o @ e depois 255 para o domínio. Isso se não permitir alguma informação extra além do RFC. Se colocar algo menor que 320 caracteres poderá ter problemas no MySQL.

Tem DBs que permitem colocar mais mesmo que usar um número menor, porque estritamente o SQL não proíbe ultrapassar esse valor que é só para indicar apresentação de dados e não uma restrição do que pode ser armazenado, ou seja, se é para usar uma *constraint* deveria ser no `CHECK`. Em geral é comum deixar a aplicação cuidar disso para evitar problemas em certos cenários. Porém no MySQL ele é só descritivo em versões antigas, somente na versão 8.0.x é que passou ser respeitado.

Dependendo de como for configurado um texto que exceda o máximo colocado poderá só cortar o excesso ou dará erro (muito melhor). Veja mais na [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html).

Quando falamos de telefones, documentos numéricos, etc., [já foi respondida com mais detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101), mas em resumo é uma questão de continuar sendo dado descritivo, não é para quantificar nada, não é para fazer contas, então nunca use um tipo numérico, escolha um `VARCHAR`, ou até mesmo um `CHAR` pode ser mais adequado porque costuma ter tamanho fixo.

[image: Controle deslizante para entrar com o número de telefone de 10 dígitos]

E a recomendação geral para esses dados é que não coloque formatação nele, ou seja, não use pontos e traços, porque o futuro pode mudar. Formatação não é informação. Claro que para tudo pode ter exceção se puder justificar a escolha de forma adequada. O que não pode em hipótese alguma é usar tipo numérico.

É uma questão mais semântica do que técnica, ainda que a técnica possa influenciar também. Mesmo que ela permita não fique tentado, use um tipo descritivo para um dado descritivo.

Inclusive casos em que precisa de algum cálculo eventual é mais interessante a conversão porque o dado ainda é descritivo. Isso vale para o CPF e outros documentos, contas bancárias, códigos e muitos outros. Esses dados possuem dígito verificador e precisará calculá-lo, então é tentador usar um tipo numérico, mas isto está equivocado. O cálculo deve ser feito em cima do dado descritivo que será convertido para numérico, só para o cálculo, em bloco ou por caractere.

Não se esqueça que telefones podem ter ramal ou até outras características e não usar só algarismos. Em alguns casos esses penduricalhos, inclusive DDD(I) deve ser um campo diferente. E celular é diferente de telefone fixo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).