# Tipo do campo CPF ou CNPJ no banco de dados VARCHAR ou INT?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, validação, modelagem, tipagem

Qual tipo do campo CPF ou CNPJ no banco de dados `VARCHAR` ou `INT`?

Já vi alguns *posts* sugerindo usar `INT` para otimizar a performance no caso de `JOIN`e filtros.

Se possuir 0 a esquerda é só completar de acordo com o tamanho do campo armazenado (CPF Ou CNPJ) para efetuar a validação.

Então qual seria a melhor abordagem?

Comment: Eu acho que a pergunta pode ser respondida objetivamente, tanto que fiz. O fato de ter uma outra resposta que só emite opinião não é culpa da pergunta.

Comment: Eu não vi nenhum valor na pergunta a princípio, mas o fato de haver uma consideração de que a resposta seja questão de opinião me fez perceber que a pergunta é útil sim (embora a resposta seja óbvia, parece que não é tão óbvia para todos).

Comment: Eu sempre utilizei `VARCHAR`, **mas apesar de não acreditar em nada que esta na internet**, já alguns comentários defendendo usar `INT`, apesar de não apresentar nenhuma fundamentação. E separando em: corpo ,filial, e controle para usar assim: `intCPFCNPJ = 000000000 and sintCPFCNPJFil = 0 and tintCPFCNPJCtrl = 90`. Achei um **gambiarra** terrível, mas achei interessante ver outras opiniões, apesar da resposta parecer obvia.

Comment: Melhor usar VARCHAR.

Comment: Eu me pergunto como a Receita Federal armazena , ela é a 'dona do circo' digamos assim. Se algum colega que trabalhe puder ingirmar ...  Acho a melhor solução caractere.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Otimização só deve ser feita se realmente for muito necessário. Eu duvido que esta otimização valha a pena em qualquer cenário.

A regra básica para seleção do tipo quando eles podem ser confundidos é para que vai usá-los. Números representam quantidades. CPF ou CNPJ são quantidades? Não, são identificadores que podem até mesmo mudar, que podem um dia ter letras (aconteceu com RG). A semântica correta para este dado é o `varchar` afinal ele é descritivo.

[image: Controle deslizante para entrar com o número de telefone de 10 dígitos]

A questão do zero à esquerda por si só já é bom bom motivo para usar `varchar`. Pra que ficar fazendo gambiarras para resolver um problema causado pelo tipo errado. Sempre digo isso pra tudo em computação e até na vida, a pessoa causa um problema e depois causa novos tentando resolver algo que ela deveria ter feito certo do início (isso acontece mais do que quase todo mundo percebe, especialmente com experientes que não consegue mais enxergar seus erros tamanho a arrogância que desenvolve, mesmo discursando o contrário).

Você sempre deve optar por `varchar` em qualquer dado até que encontre um motivo para escolher outro tipo. Um ID geral, por exemplo, tem um bom motivo para ser um `int`, ele precisa ser incrementado, você faz contas com ele. O mesmo vale para salário, preço, quantidade. Mas não vale para CEP, fone, até mesmo número de um imóvel no endereço quando este campo é separado. Um vencimento tem motivo para ser de outro tipo, você precisa classificar a informação por ordem de data, e como texto isto não funcionaria corretamente. São só alguns exemplos.

Alguns até dirão que é necessário usar o `varchar` porque ele tem pontuação além de números. Mas este não é um bom argumento já que a pontuação nem deveria ser gravada, pelo menos não na maioria das situações. Isto deveria ser resolvido na apresentação apenas, a pontuação não faz parte do dado (geralmente).

Em alguns casos um tipo numérico nem pode ser usado já que a quantidade de dígitos usado para identificar algo é maior do que o tipo numérico comporta.

Alguns dirão que nem `varchar` deve ser usado. Como o tamanho é fixo, um simples `char` resolve o problema. Mas há controvérsias quanto a isso. Dependendo do sistema de DB um tipo realmente pode ser mais vantajoso que outro mas não o suficiente para justificar, na maioria dos casos, uma escolha será feita por causa da performance. A semântica deve ser a opção primária.

Infelizmente há muita informação errada na internet sobre o assunto (ou qualquer assunto :) ).

[image: as seen on the internet]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ótima resposta! Estou apenas com uma dúvida final, você aconselha a criação de uma coluna cpf e outra cnpj ou criar apenas uma coluna para armazenar tanto um quanto o outro?

Comment: @MarcioMazzucato depende muito do caso. Hoje eu faço sempre tabelas diferentes para pessoa física e jurídica, nem precisa dizer que as coluna são separadas. Eu modelo cadastros como eles realmente são, não crio uma divisão artificial e um união mais artificial ainda. Quando gosta de algo pode votar no post. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101

Comment: @Maniero Ótima resposta, tirou toda e qualquer dúvida que esse assunto me gerava

Comment: Semanticamente `varchar` significa "campo de caracteres de tamanho variável". Como o CPF não tem tamanho variável, `char` é mais adequado do ponto de vista semântico. Além da já mencionada vantagem em relação ao desempenho.

Comment: @Maniero, rapaz, aonde tu aprendeu tudo isso? que resposta formidável!!!

Comment: @danilo em 36 anos de dedicação e estudo estruturado. Obrigado.

Comment: Sempre defendi o uso de varchar. Semana passada tive que defender novamente. Hoje por coincidência me passaram um problema numa tela. Identifiquei que ocorre apenas com usuários com CPF iniciado por zero. Logicamente tinha cpf como BIGINT no meio.

Answer (score 32):

Sempre defendi usar `VARCHAR`, pois eles são uma string que coincidentemente ocorre de serem uma sequência de dígitos. Diferentemente de um `INT` aonde a finalidade de ser um número é permitir que você possa efetuar operações matemáticas, algo que não tem sentido nenhum em um CPF ou CNPJ.

O mesmo caso ocorre com o RG, aonde cada estado tem um formato diferente, e usar como `INT` iria remover os zeros a esquerda, além de trazer problemas referentes ao dígito verificador.

Comment: Você aconselha a criação de uma coluna cpf e outra cnpj ou criar apenas uma coluna para armazenar tanto um quanto o outro?

Comment: Marcio Mazzucato, eu tenho usado a mesma coluna para armazenar CPF/CNPJ, usando entretanto um campo auxiliar "Tipo" (ex: CPF=1, CPNJ=2) para indicar o que tem na coluna principal (para facilitar algumas queries). Como eu salvo os dados com os zeros a esquerda (CPF tamanho 11, CNPJ tamanho 14) não preciso usar constraint com os 2 campos para garantir a unicidade.

Answer (score 10):

Use `VARCHAR` você terá problemas caso o usuário utilize `.` (ponto) ou/e `-` para separar os dígitos. Caso você faça alguma verificação e retire esses ou outros caracteres, então pode-se usar `INT`. Mas recomendo usar `VARCHAR`. Use `INT` para registros que você sabe que só terá dígitos/números.

Comment: só uma ponderação... você só pode saber que o campo sempre terá dígitos/números se ele estiver no teu domínio, e se a natureza dele realmente é intríssica a números, não pode ser algo controlado por agente externo como é o caso da Receita Federal que controla a definição de cpf/cnpj

Answer (score 3):

Conforme a resposta de Victor Stafusa, te ajudará a tomar a melhor decisão observar que tipos de operações serão realizadas no campo em questão. No caso do CPF e CNPJ, estes não sofrem operações aritméticas (normalmente) e são tratados como tipos de dado alfanumérico (char, varchar) desde de seus algoritmos de validação, que por definição os consideram cadeias de caracteres de tamanhos fixos. Um outro ponto a favor de serem utilizados tipos alfanuméricos como o varchar, é que fica facilitado a utilização de pesquisas usando o operador LIKE, ao contrário de campos de tipos numéricos. Campos de dados de "códigos identificadores" (como CPF e CNPJ) alfanuméricos também podem ser considerados mais a prova de futuro, pois há alguma possibilidade (talvez remota, mas há) de passar-se a utilizar letras nestes, já que cada letra aumenta em muito o número de combinações diferentes e, ao mesmo tempo, requer menos caracteres a memorizar.

Mas como tudo no mundo da computação, tudo tem seu preço e dependendo dos seus requisitos de performance e tamanho de banco de dados, pode ser muito mais performático armazenar CPFs e CNPJs como tipos numéricos, uma vez que ocupam consideravelmente menos bytes (especialmente em relação ao varchar com unicode), resultando em índices de tabela fisicamente menores, além de algoritmos de busca mais rápidos. De fato, já vi grande melhora de performance em bancos de dados Oracle ao terem CPFs armazenados como number.

Answer (score 2):

Se observarmos o tamanho do INT(UNSIGNED) que vai de 0 a 4294967295, temos 10 posições suportadas.
Como o CPF tem 11 números sem formatação, teríamos 1 número a mais nessa cadeia, forçando o DB, no momento da inserção, a fazer um CPF com valor digamos inicial de "500.000.000-60" ou se for "4294967296" virar 4294967295.

A regra vale para o CNPJ também, no caso do CNPJ com 14 números sem formatação.  O ideal seria usar um BIGINT de 0 a 18446744073709551615. Para questões de velocidade em consultas, pode ser adicionado um índice nesse campo e outras regras que vai de cada DBA.

No caso dos 0 a esquerda no MySql por exemplo podemos definir o campo como ZEROFILL.

Sobre formatação não é necessário permitir que a aplicação chegue até o DB com um CPF ou CNPJ formatado com ".", "-" ou "/", essa regra cabe ser feita em uma view.

Comment: Possível de se usar inteiro até é, mas acho complicado dizer que "é o ideal". E outra, se é para armazenar no "improviso", poderia usar um INT sem problemas, afinal um CPF válido só tem 9 digitos significativos. Os dois de conferência são calculados (a não ser que você queira armazenar mesmo se os dígitos de conferência não baterem). O fato importante é ter em mente a natureza do dado, o que já está bem elaborado nos outros posts.

Answer (score 1):

Cara te aconselho a usar uma string mesmo, pois vc pode ter problemas com 0 a esquerda pq eles podem ser desconsiderados.