# Qual atributo usar para campos da base de dados que trabalhem com números de 0 à 5?

Tags: mysql, sql, modelagem

Precisava montar uma tabela no MySQL, onde os valores gravados nessa tabela serão entre 0 e 5, quais tipos de atributo dentro do campo da tabela deve ser assumido? Que tipo de dado informamos na coluna `tipo_DADO`?

Aparentemente não foi tratado a questão do tipo conciso de dado na criação da tabela, porém na inserção e captura dessas informações da tabela elas são tratadas.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS minhabase (
id int(11) NOT NULL,
nome text NOT NULL,
dia text NOT NULL,
cpf text NOT NULL,
typedor text,
outra text,
eva text,
idor text,
cp text,
lo text,
cam text,
sen text,
fp text,
dm text,
vse text,
vsoc text,
loc text
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp850;
```

Answer (score 18):

Olhando sua modelagem vejo algumas coisas esquisitas. Primeiro vou responder o que foi perguntado.

E a pergunta está um pouco estranha também, talvez porque você não saiba os termos corretos. Ou nós não estamos entendendo sua real intenção. **Atributos** no fundo são as colunas. A interpretação das pessoas é a mesma que a minha e acho que você quer saber que tipo usar. De fato parece que você está confuso com os tipos (que no fundo aproximadamente é o que se costuma chamar de **domínio** em modelagem) a serem usados em todas suas colunas.

## Tipo da coluna

Como já comentaram se você sabe que os números possíveis ficarão entre 0 e 5 e só podem ser inteiros, o ideal é usar um inteiro com o menor espaço de armazenagem possível. Até pode usar um que permite armazenar números com valores maiores mas é desperdício. Então basta ter um tipo de 1 *byte* que permite armazenar valores entre -128 e 127 já que cada *byte* permite representar 256 valores diferentes.

Então basta usar o tipo [`tinyint`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html). Na definição da tabela pode estabelecer sem medo um tipo `tinyint(1)`. Este 1 determina quantos dígitos serão mostrados quando fizer uma consulta e no caso você só precisa de 1 dígito. Então alguns exemplos de como ficaria:

```
eva tinyint(1)
idor tinyint(1)
cam tinyint(1)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/TinyInt.sql).

Em tese você poderia garantir que só valores entre 0 e 5 poderiam ser escritos nestas colunas (ou atributos como elas são chamadas formalmente nos modelos). Por padrão os SGDBs possuem a capacidade de fazer esta restrição através da palavra-chave `check` mas [no MySQL isto é ignorado](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

## Alternativas

Outra possibilidade é utilizar uma enumeração. Pode ser que estes valores de 0 à 5 tenham uma semântica específica. Ou seja, pode ser que estes números sejam mais que números, que eles identifiquem algo com maior significado. De uma certa forma podemos entender como se fossem referências para uma tabela auxiliar para indicar o que é isto. Com o [`enum`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) você pode criar um significado para estes números e garantir que só eles podem ser usados.

Não estou dizendo que isto deve ser usado, apenas que é uma alternativa se você perceber que ele é mais adequado para o que você precisa.

## Outras colunas

Além disto não dá para identificar bem o que é cada coluna. Os nomes das colunas são estranhos. Talvez eles tenham significado para o que você está fazendo, mas talvez você só queira deixá-los curtos. Se for isto, não é um boa ideia. Dar nomes significativos é muito importante.

A coluna `dia` é um texto mesmo? Existe alguma chance de ser uma data? Se for, use o tipo [`date` ou `datetime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

A coluna `cpf` seria o CPF da pessoa? Então o tipo `tinyint` não faz sentido. Se for CPF provavelmente ele deveria ser um [`varchar(11)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html). Dados que servem como identificadores devem ser textos mesmo que eles só possuam dígitos numéricos. Outro detalhe é que você não deveria gravar formatação, o use seja, os pontos e traço do CPF, o dado é apenas a composição de dígitos. Veja [Tipo do campo CPF ou CNPJ no banco de dados VARCHAR ou INT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101).

Como tem estes erros aparentes de tipos, seria bom rever as outras colunas.

Comment: essa  sua ajuda só gerou mais dúvida, pelo menos no meu mysql não rodou! ok! grato pelas horas de paciência a fio!

Comment: Agora você pode fazer uma nova pergunta com a nova dúvida.

Comment: não há dúvidas @bigown sua sugestão não funcionou e só!

Comment: além do que essa antiga dúvida, foi auto explicativa do meu problema, pois através da exploração dele foi exposta a solução.
Basta ler com atenção que entenderá!

Comment: tipo isso era um exercicio da escola não um sistema da nasa

Comment: Não consigo até hoje entender os motivos de as pessoas votarem sua resposta como valida e útil, criei um novo banco de dados conforme sugerido e não gravou(através do form localhost) e nem leu nos testes (inserido manualmente as informações).
Vendo a tabela (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) a sua informações até são procedentes, falando da faixa máxima e mínima de valores aceitáveis dentro da variável de sistema, etc, mas sem levar em conta que só ia inserir um número em cada coluna, vc disse "se varias pessoas entenderam errado, não são as pessoas é a pergunta"...

Comment: então vai ver não só minha tabela de dados mas meu form php tb está tudo errado nem sei como funciona e agora?? @bigown estou sem dúvida quanto a sua dúvida!!

Comment: @SUP9RPI46 Não entendi como isso não funcionou, no mysql não existe check então não tem como checar no campo. Ele ainda te deu um campo que apresenta apenas um dígito. Se tu quer um check desses, precisa fazer no programa que faz a inserção dos dados no banco, e não direto no banco de dados.