# Campos de telefone e CPF no SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

Estou com dúvida de que tipo de variável criar para os campos de CPF e Telefone no banco de dados, eles devem ser salvos assim:

```
(34) 9652-5214
134.124.214-47
```

Com `nchar` não complicaria na busca? Mas no caso do nchar, como coloco pra ele não poder armazenar letras? E como coloco para quando o usuário buscar, poder buscar só pelos números, sem () etc? Só colocar mascará no campo de busca?

Comment: Pra que gravar a mascará?

Comment: Eu gravaria apenas os números e aplicaria máscara na hora de realizar o registro, visualizar a consulta ou fazer uma busca.

Comment: em outro form vou exibir uma tabela como `DataGridView` daí lá pra  ficar exibindo com pontuação etc.. Ou dá pra por mascara? Se der então pode gravar sem mascara. O problema é que não dá pra colocar `int` pois variavel int tem limite curto de tamanho

Comment: Grave ambos sem mascara em campo do tipo texto e quando for exibir formate como deseja na saída

Comment: ok, mas tipo campo texto armazena letra também, tem como fazer para ler somente números? Como `int` e `numeric`?

Comment: Você faz o tratamento no campo que está recebendo esses dados no c#. Você vai usar o que? `TextBox` normal mesmo?

Comment: sim sim, apenas textbox

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47871/tipo-do-campo-cpf-ou-cnpj-no-banco-de-dados-varchar-ou-int/47873#47873

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No C# existe um componente chamado `MaskedTextBox`. Nele é possível especificar uma máscara para o campo.
Por exemplo no seu campo telefone pode ser a máscara: `(##) #####-####` na propriedade `Mask`. Ele aceitará somente numéricos.
Na hora de ler o valor, você utilizará o seguinte código:

```
this.maskedTextBox1.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
String telefone = this.maskedTextBox1.Text;
```

Assim você terá apenas números na String `telefone`, para assim salvar no banco de dados.

Comment: no caso eu declararia os dois campos do banco de dados como `nchar(14)` né?

Comment: Não precisei nem da segunda linha, só mudando o formato da mascara ele já grava sem a mascara.. Vlw

Answer (score 1):

Qual é o banco de dados?

Para o CPF aconselho utilizar o tipo Char e especificar um tamanho de 11 caracteres, isso sem guardar os pontos e o hífen.

Para o telefone aconselho um campo VARCHAR de tamanho máximo 11, já que em algumas regiões do país utilizam um campo a mais ou um campo a menos.

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD COLUMN cpf CHAR(11);
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD COLUMN telefone VARCHAR(11);
```

Espero que esta resposta tenha ajudado, qualquer dúvida estamos a disposição.

Comment: mas aí que tá, `char` e `varchar` aceitam letras etc, daí se o bixinho de orelha (usuário) gravar dado errado é considerado falha no sistema, tem como restringir uma char ou varchar para ler apenas números?

Comment: Faça a verificação no servidor, quando a aplicação for salvar os dados, se não for feita a verificação quem vai retornar erro para a aplicação vai ser o banco de dados. Veja sobre a diferença entre char e varchar, o char sempre armazena um tamanho fixo para a coluna.

Answer (score 1):

Todas as verificações você pode fazer antes de armazenar no Banco de dados as informações, por exemplo um formulário pode ter mascara que adiciona o (xx) xxxx-xxxx, mas você faz um tratamento para remover os demais caracteres que não sejam número, desta forma armazenando apenas número em um varchar no banco.

Lembrando se você quer que seja verificado o valor antes de enviar para confirmar que esta mandando apenas dígitos corretos, utilize expressão regular para reconhecer a cadeia algo como `([0-9]{2})\s[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}` não estou falando que esta expressão regular é a certa, mas é algo bem próximo do que você pode usar, assim ele vai obrigar que tenha dois números no DDD entre parênteses e 8 números seguidos separados por -.

Isto já garante, depois um split ou um tokenizer dependendo do que você usar para separar e remover o que não é digito, e concatena todo o resto como número e salva no banco de dados.

Quando for acessar, para apresentar os dados da forma visual só criar uma mascara novamente para aplicar em cima do valor restaurado. Como banco de dados os valores precisam estar corretos, os tratamentos quem faz e sempre o programa para pegar o valor e demonstrar, pelo menos a melhor forma para você pensar é esta.