# Como seleciono múltiplos campos em uma mesma consulta?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Criei um banco fictício com a seguinte estrutura:

[image: Esquema Lógico]

Seguem abaixo também os scripts do SQL Server numerados para criação do banco, caso seja necessário.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd4e4)

Agora, o que quero é fazer uma consulta onde sejam mostrados:

1. O limite de um titular adicional - presente na tabela **Titulares_Adicionais**
2. O nome desse cliente - presente na tabela **Cliente**
3. O grau de parentesco desse cliente - também em **Titulares_Adicionais**
4. De quem esse titular depende - também na tabela **Cliente**, referenciado na tabela **Conta**

Comment: Está difícil entender, escreva a estrutura das tabelas e como quer o resultado. Tem coisas aí que não parecem fazer sentido. Se quiser pode até usar o http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ para montar toda a estrutura, colocar dados e a gente monta a *query* pra você.

Comment: @bigown editei o post, tive que reduzir o esquema desse banco para postar, mas agora ficou bem mais claro - acredito eu.

Comment: Posso estar enganado porque a modelagem é um pouco confusa mas me parece que você não quer uma consulta e sim várias, não parece que exista relação direta pelo menos entre algumas destas informações. Parece estranho essas relações. E uma dica, só coloque como número o que realmente precisa ser número. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101 Eu lembrei que preciso dar uma mexida na resposta em outra pergunta sua. Te ensinaram fazer algo confuso lá e parece que você gostou da confusão :) Não coloque zip, faça um fiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd4e4

Comment: Sim claro, irei testar e já te falo, não consegui usar o SQL Fiddle, quando eu ia executar o script para inserir os dados ele dava erro - conferi o código e executei no MS SQL Server normalmente.

De qualquer forma, obrigado pela resposta e pelas dicas, com certeza tomarei nota :)

Comment: Eu executei os seus *scripts* sem mudar uma vírgula sequer :)

Comment: Ah sim agora eu vi, eu coloquei apenas as tabelas no lado esquerdo onde se constrói o esquema, e tentei fazer o restante do lado direito, e olhando aqui do jeito que você fez os scripts estão todos na construção do esquema. Interessante...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi, é mais ou menos isto (espero não ter interpretado nada errado):

```
SELECT Titulares_Adicionais.Limite, Titulares_Adicionais.Grau_Parentesco,
    Conta.Cod_Titular, Cliente.Nome
FROM Titulares_Adicionais
INNER JOIN Conta ON Titulares_Adicionais.Cod_Conta = Conta.Codigo
INNER JOIN Cliente ON Titulares_Adicionais.Cod_Cli = Cliente.Codigo
WHERE Titulares_Adicionais.Cod_Cli = 5;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/DualJoin.sql).

No fundo o primeiro `INNER JOIN` é desnecessário aí, mas deixei se quiser sofisticar e quiser pegar informações dela, tá fácil. Note que nenhum dado é pego da tabela `Conta`, por isso ele não é necessário.

Já o segundo é necessário porque pega o `Nome` lá na tabela `Cliente`.

O [`INNER JOIN`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/101) ou só `JOIN` é que relaciona as tabelas que precisa baseado nas colunas definidas.

Comment: Véi, você é foda, não é que funcionou mesmo - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd4e4/1/0 - ainda vou chegar no INNER JOIN, é por isso que eu não estava sabendo. Na verdade  me disseram que só um SELECT dava. ;
De qualquer maneira muito obrigado :)