# Quantidade de caracteres do CPF, CNPJ e RG

Tags: validação, modelagem

Estou fazendo um programa que precisa validar uma série de documentos - CPF, CNPJ e, se possível, RG.

Minhas questões são as seguintes:

1. Existem CNPJs válidos com número de caracteres menor que 14?
   (ex: empresas antigas). 

   Formato comum: xx.xxx.xxx/xxxx-xx 

   Caso sim, qual número mínimo de caracteres para um CNPJ ser válido?
2. Existem CPFs válidos com número de caracteres menor que 11?
       (ex: pessoas idosas) 
   Formato comum: xxx.xxx.xxx-xx 
   Caso sim,
       qual número mínimo de caracteres para um CPF ser válido?
3. Existem RGs válidos com número de caracteres menor(1) ou
       maior(2) que 9?(ex: pessoas idosas(1) ou crianças (2)) 
   Formato
       comum: xx.xxx.xxx-x 
   Caso sim, qual número mínimo e qual número
       máximo de caracteres para um RG ser válido?

Comment: RG depende do UF. Cada UF tem um formato. O resto é fixo (prefixado com zero se for o caso). Um RG 98.236 é válido.

Comment: Um RG pode ser maior que um CPF?

Comment: Imagino que não. Mas o lugar dos pontos e se vai ter digito ou não, pode ser diferente. Melhor coisa pra RG é campo livre, e um campo separado para emissor.  Melhor ainda é ter um campo "documento de identidade" e um campo "órgão emissor", pois pode nem ser um RG a identificação da pessoa. De repente é um registro de estrangeiro.

Comment: O RG da minha mãe, da Bahia, nascida em 64, tinha mais de 10 digitos até recentemente.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida se esse mais de dez for também mais de onze, realmente é maior que um CPF.

Comment: Erros comuns na implementação da validação desses dados cadastrais: permitir apenas números na máscara do RG (alguns dígitos verificadores são X, o certo é não usar máscara); proibir CPF 000.000.000-00 e o mesmo com outros números repetidos (esses CPFs são válidos).

Comment: @vnbrs a pergunta é sobre validação, se for colocar tag brasil em toda as perguntas de validação de cpf e cnpj, essa tag seria uma das mais utilizadas. Não vejo sentido algum colocar nessa pergunta apenas.

Comment: @CuriousElf Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: Segue validador Java no seguinte [link](https://github.com/jereztech/validation-br-api)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Existem CNPJs válidos com número de caracteres menor que 14? (ex: empresas antigas)

O formato é este para todas empresas nacionais. Um dia pode mudar, mas hoje é sempre assim.

Alguns sistemas podem ter que lidar com empresas estrangeiras, aí é bem diferente. Mas isto é algo secundário em sistemas, não tem base em operações brasileiras e mesmo em sistemas que fazem operações internacionais é essencialmente descritivo.

> Existem CPFs válidos com número de caracteres menor que 11? (ex: pessoas idosas)

Não existe nada diferente.

O que pode ocorrer é um dia mudar. Pode ser que o CPF até deixe de existir um dia e dar lugar a outra documento. Está em curso o [documento único](https://www12.senado.leg.br/noticias/materias/2017/05/11/sancionada-lei-que-cria-documento-unico-de-identificacao). Mas por enquanto não é uma substituição.

> Existem RGs válidos com número de caracteres menor(1) ou maior(2) que 9?(ex: pessoas idosas(1) ou crianças (2))

Sim, cada estado é de um jeito, pode ter diferenças entre órgãos de emissão diferentes no mesmo estado e dependendo da época pode diferir também. É difícil criar uma máscara.

[A Receita Federal tem um documento](https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/acsrf/PortariaSRFCotec0022003.pdf) indicando que o máximo é 11, mas não é oficial, eu acho que tem maior.

Existem critérios de validação do CNPJ e CPF. Alguns estados possuem fórmulas de validação de seu Registro Geral (irônico nome).

Em geral o RG precisa ser deixado bem livre. Me parece que 13 ou 14 é seguro.

[Pode ser útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101). E [sobre máscaras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233709/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

**Sobre CPF e CNPJ**

**CPF** 11 digitos e o nono digito é referente a localidade

> A Região Fiscal onde emitido o CPF (definida pelo nono dígito) tem a
>   seguinte abrangência: 1 (DF-GO-MS-MT-TO), 2 (AC-AM-AP-PA-RO-RR), 3
>   (CE-MA-PI), 4 (AL-PB-PE-RN), 5 (BA-SE), 6 (MG), 7 (ES-RJ), 8 (SP), 9
>   (PR-SC) e 0 (RS)

**CNPJ** 14 digitos

> No passado, os números eram agrupados por Estado. Hoje está tudo
>   misturado e por isso XX.XXX.XXX os 8 primeiros números são emitidos
>   sequencialmente a partir dos números já criados. Desta forma, qualquer
>   pessoa com mais de 10 neurônios consegue chegar ao CNPJ das empresas
>   novas. É assim que algumas pessoas pegam o seu CNPJ e enviam malas
>   diretas e boletos falsos.

***Referencia(e recomendo a leitura):*** https://atendimento.contadorx.com/hc/pt-br/articles/205698465-O-que-%C3%A9-CNPJ-

**RG** é mais complicado, por que cada estado tem um formato diferente e existe a possibilidade de de duas pessoas de estados diferentes possuirem a mesma numeracao, para validar um rg é necessario saber a regra de criacao de cada estado.

Answer (score 2):

A quantidade de dígitos de CNPJ e CPF são fixas, como os colegas já apontaram.
O RG é complicado mas a sugestão do @Bacco, de utilizar também o campo 'Emissor',  é boa. 
Acrescente também a UF de emissão pois não é ilegal que uma pessoa tenha RGs emitidos em mais de uma UF.
fonte ([[http://portalcatalao.com/cbcaixa/painel/upload/manuais/manual_caixa.pdf]](http://portalcatalao.com/cbcaixa/painel/upload/manuais/manual_caixa.pdf#page=7))