# Gravar registros com a máscara ou remover antes?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mask

Contextualizando minha pergunta, meio que por convenção de meu antigo ambiente de trabalho sempre gravei os registros sem a máscara na base, mas surgiu uma situação no meu novo emprego em que eles estão salvando os registros com a máscara.

Até onde eu sei o "correto" é salvar sem a máscara, mas não tenho argumentos para justificar meu ponto, o que eu gostaria são justificativas de porque os registros deveriam ser salvos desta forma no banco.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existem argumentos para os dois lados. Particularmente acho que o correto é sem a máscara porque a máscara geralmente é só uma apresentação visual do dado, ela não faz parte do dado, a máscara é algo estranho ao dado, então conceitualmente seria errado usá-la. Sempre prefiro adotar o que é conceitualmente correto porque isso tende a dar menos problemas no futuro.

Claro que não vale se a máscara faz parte do dado, se não há uma padronização ou coisas assim. Um RG não pode ter máscara, varia para cada estado, época e outras coisas, por outro lado as pessoas provavelmente preencherão com máscara. Como ele é só descritivo não importa muito.

O principal argumento para usá-la no dado é que pode simplificar a programação em alguns casos. Dependendo da tecnologia usada pode ter que preparar o dado com a máscara antes de usá-lo ou depois de recebê-lo.

Um argumento para não usar é que a máscara pode mudar um dia e criar complicadores para adaptar o dado.

No passado existia o argumento que sem a máscara economiza espaço, hoje isso costuma ser irrelevante.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O dígito verificador do RG não pode causar confusão? Ou ele é, sempre foi e sempre será fixo?

Comment: Sempre pode mudar. Há algum tempo sequer tinha dígito.

Comment: O correto então é colocar o dígito verificador numa outra coluna? Se não me engano o formato do RG ou do CPF é estadual, ou seja, pode ser que mudem alguns e não todos, na hora de formatar vai virar confusão certo?

Comment: Não, o dígito faz parte do código. o RG é estadual (ele vai morrer em alguns anos), como dito, é só descritivo. Por ter várias máscaras fica difícil gravar sem ela. Até dá para fazer isso já que o RG sempre precisa do órgão emissor que indica de que estado é e permite aplicar, mas complica, fora que pode acontecer de ter máscaras de acordo com a época.