# Por que o CPF está imprimindo o valor incorreto?

Tags: c, tipagem

Por que o CPF está imprimindo o valor 6422276?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
int dia;
int mes;
int ano;
}data;

typedef struct{
char nome[100];
data nascimento;
int cpf[10];
}ficha;

ficha *preenche(ficha *ponteiro){
//NOME
printf("NOME:\n");
fgets(ponteiro->nome,100,stdin);
setbuf(stdin,0);

//data de nascimento
printf("DATA DE NASCIMENTO: <dia><mes><ano> \n");
scanf("%d %d %d",&ponteiro->nascimento.dia,&ponteiro- 
>nascimento.mes,&ponteiro->nascimento.ano );
setbuf(stdin,0);

//CPF
printf("CPF:\n");
scanf("%d", &ponteiro->cpf);

return ponteiro;
}


void imprimi(ficha *ponteiro){
printf("NOME>>>%s\n", ponteiro->nome);

printf("DATA DE NASCIMENTO>>> <%d><%d><%d> \n", ponteiro- 
>nascimento.dia,ponteiro->nascimento.mes,ponteiro->nascimento.ano);

printf("CPF>>>>%d\n",ponteiro->cpf);

}

int main() {
ficha pessoa;
ficha *p;
p=&pessoa;

p=preenche(p);
imprimi(p);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O tipo do `CPF` pode ser uma string, ou um vetor de `chars` com tamanho `11 + 1`.

Um número de CPF é composto por `11` digitos, seu buffer precisa ter um tamanho minímo de `12` elementos para ser capaz de reter um CPF, onde o ultimo elemento serve para acomodar o terminador `\0`.

Veja só:

```
#define CPF_TAM_MAX     (11)
#define NOME_TAM_MAX    (100)

typedef struct {
    char nome[ NOME_TAM_MAX + 1 ];
    data nascimento;
    char cpf[ CPF_TAM_MAX + 1 ];
} ficha;
```

Agora, altere a linha:

```
scanf( "%d", &ponteiro->cpf );
```

Para:

```
scanf( "%s", ponteiro->cpf );
```

Ao ler uma linha com `fgets()`, o caractere de final de linha `\n` e/ou `\r` não são removidos do final do buffer:

```
fgets( ponteiro->nome, 100, stdin );
```

Inclua a [seguinte linha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) para remove-los de forma segura:

```
ponteiro->nome[ strcspn(ponteiro->nome, "\r\n") ] = 0;
```

Juntado tudo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CPF_TAM_MAX     (11)
#define NOME_TAM_MAX    (100)

typedef struct {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
} data;


typedef struct {
    char nome[ NOME_TAM_MAX + 1 ];
    data nascimento;
    char cpf[ CPF_TAM_MAX + 1 ];
} ficha;


void preencher(ficha *ponteiro)
{
    printf("NOME: ");
    fgets( ponteiro->nome, NOME_TAM_MAX, stdin );
    ponteiro->nome[strcspn(ponteiro->nome, "\r\n")] = 0;
    setbuf( stdin, 0 );

    printf("DATA DE NASCIMENTO (DD MM AAAA): ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&ponteiro->nascimento.dia,&ponteiro->nascimento.mes,&ponteiro->nascimento.ano );
    setbuf(stdin,0);

    printf("CPF: ");
    scanf( "%s", ponteiro->cpf);
}


void imprimir(ficha *ponteiro)
{
    printf("NOME: %s\n", ponteiro->nome );
    printf("DATA DE NASCIMENTO: %02d/%02d/%04d\n", ponteiro->nascimento.dia, ponteiro->nascimento.mes, ponteiro->nascimento.ano );
    printf("CPF: %s\n", ponteiro->cpf );
}

int main( void )
{
    ficha pessoa;
    preencher( &pessoa );
    imprimir( &pessoa );
    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
NOME: Fulano de Tal
DATA DE NASCIMENTO (DD MM AAAA): 03 07 2018
CPF: 00011122299
NOME: Fulano de Tal
DATA DE NASCIMENTO: 03/07/2018
CPF: 00011122299
```

Answer (score 3):

CPF não é um número é uma descrição composta por algarismos, não é um número, especialmente não é um *array* com 10 inteiros, isso não faz o menor sentido, poderia até fazer se fosse um `long`, mas ainda estaria errado porque CPF não é um número.

Mude na `ficha` para `char cpf[12]` ([fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245294/101)) e aí consegue guardar o CPF, aí no `printf()` mude para `%s`.

Veja [Tipo do campo CPF ou CNPJ no banco de dados VARCHAR ou INT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101).

Tem outros erros menores no código, ou outros maiores que eu nem prestei atenção.