# Máscara de CPF/CNPJ não consegue validar CPF

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou montando um validador de CPF e CNPJ com máscara. O problema é que não está montando a máscara corretamente no CPF.

Como corrigir esse erro?

O código faz o seguinte:

No momento da digitação a máscara deve ser montada, quando a pessoa sai do campo aí é feita a validação do valor digitado, caso seja válido faz a consulta via `getJSON`.

Testem logo abaixo para ver como a máscara fica ao digitar o CPF.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.validate').cpfcnpj({
    mask: true,
    validate: 'cpfcnpj',
    event: 'focusout',
    //validateOnlyFocus: true,
    handler: '.validate',
    ifValid: function(input) {
      input.removeClass("error");
      $("#cpf_cnpj").ready(function() {
        valor = $("#cpf_cnpj").val().replace(/[^0-9\s]/gi, '');
        $.getJSON("buscaCliente.php", {
          cpf_cnpj: valor
        }, function(json) {

          $("#cleinteID").val(json[0].cleinteID);
          $("#nomeCliente").val(json[0].nomeCliente);
          $("#chaveCliente").val(json[0].chaveCliente);


          if (json[0].cleinteID == 0) {
            $(".cadEsconder").show();
            $(".cadMostrar").hide();
          } else {
            $(".cadEsconder").hide();
            $(".cadMostrar").show();
          }

        });
      });
    },
    ifInvalid: function(input) {
      input.addClass("error");
      //alert("CPF/CNPJ Inválido.");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cpfcnpj.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control validate" name="cpf_cnpj" id="cpf_cnpj" placeholder="Digite">
```

Comment: Para quem quiser resolver o problema, basta mudar a versão do jQuery para: > `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece por você está implementando o mesmo bloco de código de dois dados, que embora sejam do mesmo tipo, tem tamanhos e formatos diferentes quando recebem caracteres especiais, causando maior probabilidade de falha humana na hora de inserir esses caracteres na implementação.

O recomendado na maior parte dos casos é manter estes blocos de código separados para cada formato, e eles serem disparados em contextos diferentes. Ou ao detectar X quantidade de caracteres, disparar Y máscara. [No caso de CPF, 11 dígitos, no caso de CNPJs, 14 dígitos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121593/quantidade-de-caracteres-do-cpf-cnpj-e-rg).

No entanto, é sim possível manter o mesmo bloco de códigos para tratar dados com formatos diferentes, como mostra [este link](https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2014/11/como-validar-cpf-e-cnpj-com-javascript-ou-jquery/). As desvantagens são arquivos de código mais extensos, portanto mais difícil manutenção e aumento de probabilidade de falha humana. Segue o código da fonte abaixo:

**valida_cpf_cnpj.js**

```
/*
 verifica_cpf_cnpj

 Verifica se é CPF ou CNPJ

 @see http://www.tutsup.com/
*/
function verifica_cpf_cnpj ( valor ) {

    // Garante que o valor é uma string
    valor = valor.toString();

    // Remove caracteres inválidos do valor
    valor = valor.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

    // Verifica CPF
    if ( valor.length === 11 ) {
        return 'CPF';
    } 

    // Verifica CNPJ
    else if ( valor.length === 14 ) {
        return 'CNPJ';
    } 

    // Não retorna nada
    else {
        return false;
    }

} // verifica_cpf_cnpj

/*
 calc_digitos_posicoes

 Multiplica dígitos vezes posições

 @param string digitos Os digitos desejados
 @param string posicoes A posição que vai iniciar a regressão
 @param string soma_digitos A soma das multiplicações entre posições e dígitos
 @return string Os dígitos enviados concatenados com o último dígito
*/
function calc_digitos_posicoes( digitos, posicoes = 10, soma_digitos = 0 ) {

    // Garante que o valor é uma string
    digitos = digitos.toString();

    // Faz a soma dos dígitos com a posição
    // Ex. para 10 posições:
    //   0    2    5    4    6    2    8    8   4
    // x10   x9   x8   x7   x6   x5   x4   x3  x2
    //   0 + 18 + 40 + 28 + 36 + 10 + 32 + 24 + 8 = 196
    for ( var i = 0; i < digitos.length; i++  ) {
        // Preenche a soma com o dígito vezes a posição
        soma_digitos = soma_digitos + ( digitos[i] * posicoes );

        // Subtrai 1 da posição
        posicoes--;

        // Parte específica para CNPJ
        // Ex.: 5-4-3-2-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2
        if ( posicoes < 2 ) {
            // Retorno a posição para 9
            posicoes = 9;
        }
    }

    // Captura o resto da divisão entre soma_digitos dividido por 11
    // Ex.: 196 % 11 = 9
    soma_digitos = soma_digitos % 11;

    // Verifica se soma_digitos é menor que 2
    if ( soma_digitos < 2 ) {
        // soma_digitos agora será zero
        soma_digitos = 0;
    } else {
        // Se for maior que 2, o resultado é 11 menos soma_digitos
        // Ex.: 11 - 9 = 2
        // Nosso dígito procurado é 2
        soma_digitos = 11 - soma_digitos;
    }

    // Concatena mais um dígito aos primeiro nove dígitos
    // Ex.: 025462884 + 2 = 0254628842
    var cpf = digitos + soma_digitos;

    // Retorna
    return cpf;

} // calc_digitos_posicoes

/*
 Valida CPF

 Valida se for CPF

 @param  string cpf O CPF com ou sem pontos e traço
 @return bool True para CPF correto - False para CPF incorreto
*/
function valida_cpf( valor ) {

    // Garante que o valor é uma string
    valor = valor.toString();

    // Remove caracteres inválidos do valor
    valor = valor.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');


    // Captura os 9 primeiros dígitos do CPF
    // Ex.: 02546288423 = 025462884
    var digitos = valor.substr(0, 9);

    // Faz o cálculo dos 9 primeiros dígitos do CPF para obter o primeiro dígito
    var novo_cpf = calc_digitos_posicoes( digitos );

    // Faz o cálculo dos 10 dígitos do CPF para obter o último dígito
    var novo_cpf = calc_digitos_posicoes( novo_cpf, 11 );

    // Verifica se o novo CPF gerado é idêntico ao CPF enviado
    if ( novo_cpf === valor ) {
        // CPF válido
        return true;
    } else {
        // CPF inválido
        return false;
    }

} // valida_cpf

/*
 valida_cnpj

 Valida se for um CNPJ

 @param string cnpj
 @return bool true para CNPJ correto
*/
function valida_cnpj ( valor ) {

    // Garante que o valor é uma string
    valor = valor.toString();

    // Remove caracteres inválidos do valor
    valor = valor.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');


    // O valor original
    var cnpj_original = valor;

    // Captura os primeiros 12 números do CNPJ
    var primeiros_numeros_cnpj = valor.substr( 0, 12 );

    // Faz o primeiro cálculo
    var primeiro_calculo = calc_digitos_posicoes( primeiros_numeros_cnpj, 5 );

    // O segundo cálculo é a mesma coisa do primeiro, porém, começa na posição 6
    var segundo_calculo = calc_digitos_posicoes( primeiro_calculo, 6 );

    // Concatena o segundo dígito ao CNPJ
    var cnpj = segundo_calculo;

    // Verifica se o CNPJ gerado é idêntico ao enviado
    if ( cnpj === cnpj_original ) {
        return true;
    }

    // Retorna falso por padrão
    return false;

} // valida_cnpj

/*
 valida_cpf_cnpj

 Valida o CPF ou CNPJ

 @access public
 @return bool true para válido, false para inválido
*/
function valida_cpf_cnpj ( valor ) {

    // Verifica se é CPF ou CNPJ
    var valida = verifica_cpf_cnpj( valor );

    // Garante que o valor é uma string
    valor = valor.toString();

    // Remove caracteres inválidos do valor
    valor = valor.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');


    // Valida CPF
    if ( valida === 'CPF' ) {
        // Retorna true para cpf válido
        return valida_cpf( valor );
    } 

    // Valida CNPJ
    else if ( valida === 'CNPJ' ) {
        // Retorna true para CNPJ válido
        return valida_cnpj( valor );
    } 

    // Não retorna nada
    else {
        return false;
    }

} // valida_cpf_cnpj

/*
 formata_cpf_cnpj

 Formata um CPF ou CNPJ

 @access public
 @return string CPF ou CNPJ formatado
*/
function formata_cpf_cnpj( valor ) {

    // O valor formatado
    var formatado = false;

    // Verifica se é CPF ou CNPJ
    var valida = verifica_cpf_cnpj( valor );

    // Garante que o valor é uma string
    valor = valor.toString();

    // Remove caracteres inválidos do valor
    valor = valor.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');


    // Valida CPF
    if ( valida === 'CPF' ) {

        // Verifica se o CPF é válido
        if ( valida_cpf( valor ) ) {

            // Formata o CPF ###.###.###-##
            formatado  = valor.substr( 0, 3 ) + '.';
            formatado += valor.substr( 3, 3 ) + '.';
            formatado += valor.substr( 6, 3 ) + '-';
            formatado += valor.substr( 9, 2 ) + '';

        }

    }

    // Valida CNPJ
    else if ( valida === 'CNPJ' ) {

        // Verifica se o CNPJ é válido
        if ( valida_cnpj( valor ) ) {

            // Formata o CNPJ ##.###.###/####-##
            formatado  = valor.substr( 0,  2 ) + '.';
            formatado += valor.substr( 2,  3 ) + '.';
            formatado += valor.substr( 5,  3 ) + '/';
            formatado += valor.substr( 8,  4 ) + '-';
            formatado += valor.substr( 12, 14 ) + '';

        }

    } 

    // Retorna o valor 
    return formatado;

} // formata_cpf_cnpj
```

**exemplo_1.js**

```
// Testando a validação usando jQuery
$(function(){

    // ## EXEMPLO 1
    // Aciona a validação a cada tecla pressionada
    var temporizador = false;
    $('.cpf_cnpj').keypress(function(){

        // O input que estamos utilizando
        var input = $(this);

        // Limpa o timeout antigo
        if ( temporizador ) {
            clearTimeout( temporizador );
        }

        // Cria um timeout novo de 500ms
        temporizador = setTimeout(function(){
            // Remove as classes de válido e inválido
            input.removeClass('valido');
            input.removeClass('invalido');

            // O CPF ou CNPJ
            var cpf_cnpj = input.val();

            // Valida
            var valida = valida_cpf_cnpj( cpf_cnpj );

            // Testa a validação
            if ( valida ) {
                input.addClass('valido');
            } else {
                input.addClass('invalido');
            }
        }, 500);

    });
});
```

**exemplo_2.js**

```
// Testando a validação usando jQuery
$(function(){

    // ## EXEMPLO 2
    // Aciona a validação ao sair do input
    $('.cpf_cnpj').blur(function(){

        // O CPF ou CNPJ
        var cpf_cnpj = $(this).val();

        // Testa a validação
        if ( valida_cpf_cnpj( cpf_cnpj ) ) {
            alert('OK');
        } else {
            alert('CPF ou CNPJ inválido!');
        }

    });

});
```

**exemplo_3.js**

```
// Testando a validação usando jQuery
$(function(){

    // ## EXEMPLO 3
    // Aciona a validação e formatação ao sair do input
    $('.cpf_cnpj').blur(function(){

        // O CPF ou CNPJ
        var cpf_cnpj = $(this).val();

        // Testa a validação e formata se estiver OK
        if ( formata_cpf_cnpj( cpf_cnpj ) ) {
            $(this).val( formata_cpf_cnpj( cpf_cnpj ) );
        } else {
            alert('CPF ou CNPJ inválido!');
        }

    });

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Tutsup - Valida CPF e CNPJ</title>

        <style>
        .valido {
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
        .invalido {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        </style>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Funções para validação de CPF e CNPJ -->
        <script src="valida_cpf_cnpj.js"></script>

        <!-- EXEMPLOS -->

        <!-- Pressionando teclas -->
        <script src="exemplo_1.js"></script>

        <!-- Após sair do campo -->
        <script src="exemplo_2.js"></script>     

        <!-- Formatando o CPF ou CNPJ -->
        <script src="exemplo_3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="cpf_cnpj">
    </body>
</html>
```

A intenção desta resposta não é dizer que uma boa prática deva ser uma "receita de bolo". Ao contrário! Existem "n" contextos para "n" problemas. Só saiba as vantagens e desvantagens de cada tipo de implementação.