# PostgreSQL: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint ~~* unknown

Tags: postgresql

Estou fazendo um filtro com paginação no cakephp, porém quando eu digito um número de telefone para pesquisar, ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint ~~* unknown LINE 1: ...`om"."status_id_destino") WHERE "User"."telefone" ILIKE '%53`... ^
>
> HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Qualquer valor que eu digite neste campo, recebo este erro!

(NOTA: Os outros filtros funcionam normalmente, somente este que é um campo `INTEGER` que não está funcionando)

**Editada:**
Acrescentando trecho da consulta:

```
 SELECT "User"."id", "User"."telefone", "User"."email" .... etc ...
 FROM "public"."users" AS "User" .... etc ...
 WHERE "User"."telefone" ILIKE '%5332733535%'
        AND "Home"."ativo" = 'TRUE'
        AND "Home"."status_id_destino"
             IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
 ORDER BY "Ose"."id" asc LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Coloca o techo da consulta com o problema, telefone é character varying?

Comment: `telefone` é do tipo integer.

Editado!

Comment: Telefone não deveria um integer, por dois motivos, primeiro se vc tiver um 0800 vai ter problemas pq o zero a esquerda vai sumir. Um integer representa uma quantia (algo contavel) um telefone não é contavel, ele deveria ser uma character varying, não da para aplicar uma `LIKE/ILIKE` em um integer ou tipo númerico. Sugiro que mude o tipo da coluna ou crie uma nova, do contrario tente fazer um cast antes de chamar o `ilike`

Comment: Hmmm, ok, obrigado pelas sugestões.
Então eu faria algo como ...`WHERE "User"."telefone"::varchar ILIKE ......`  ??

Comment: Mais ou menos isso, não tenho certeza se ele vai aceitar o `varchar`

Comment: Fazendo a pesquisa manualmente ele funcionou dessa maneira, agora estou tentando aplicar no código. Assim que eu tiver um retorno eu coloco aqui. obrigado novamente!

Comment: Se tiver interesse veja: [Tipo do campo CPF ou CNPJ no banco de dados VARCHAR ou INT?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/91) é praticamente o mesmo problema (tipo do dado).

Comment: Perfeito @rray!
Exclareceu muita coisa pra mim, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resposta:** Conforme foi discutido, pode ser feito dessa maneira:

```
 SELECT "User"."id", "User"."telefone", "User"."email" .... etc ...
 FROM "public"."users" AS "User" .... etc ...
 WHERE "User"."telefone"::varchar ILIKE '%5332733535%'
        AND "Home"."ativo" = 'TRUE'
        AND "Home"."status_id_destino"
             IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
 ORDER BY "Ose"."id" asc LIMIT 20
```

Dando um `CASTING` antes do `ILIKE` 
ou conforme o [Tipo do campo CPF ou CNPJ no banco de dados VARCHAR ou INT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/91) fornecido pelo [rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray), a melhor opção seria trocar o tipo do campo `telefone` para `varchar`.