# Gravar no BD sem máscara aplicada pelo jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Estou fazendo um projeto em MVC e com o uso de jQuery fiz máscara de CPF conforme abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
    $(".cpf").addClass("form-control");
});
```

Segue a minha `div`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cliente_CPF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cliente_CPF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "cpf" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cliente_CPF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

A máscara está funcionando corretamente, porém eu preciso que essa informação seja gravada no meu BD sem a máscara! Apenas os números do CPF.

Como eu devo fazer?

Comment: Acredito que se você adicionar uma função ao evento `submit` do formulário e dentro dela fazer algo como `$(".cpf").val($(".cpf").val().replace(/^\D+/g, ''))` funcionaria, pois estaria removendo qualquer caractere que não é um dígito.

Answer (score 1):

Vejo duas opções: (1) tratar o valor no lado do cliente com JavaScript (2) tratar o valor no lado do servidor com C#. Para total garantia, pode implementar as duas formas.

**JavaScript**

Com JavaScript, você pode atribuir uma função ao evento `submit` do formulário e nesta função remover todos os caracteres que não são dígitos do CPF.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
    $(".cpf").addClass("form-control");

    // vvvvv--- Lembre-se de colocar o seletor correto para o seu caso:
    $("#form").submit(function () {
        var cpfValue = $(".cpf").val();

        // Remove os caracteres que não são dígitos:
        cpfValue = cpfValue.replace(/\D/g, '');

       // Atualiza o valor no campo do formulário:
       $(".cpf").val( cpfValue );
    });
});
```

Desta forma, o valor enviado será apenas numérico.

**C#**

Esta linguagem não é minha área, mas uma pesquisa rápida vi que você pode fazer algo como:

```
string cpfOnlyDigits = Regex.Replace(cpf, "[^\d]", "");
```

Então no banco de dados, ao invés de salvar o valor de `cpf`, que seria o valor recebido na requisição HTTP, você salvaria o valor de `cpfOnlyDigits`, sendo o valor filtrado, com apenas dígitos.

Comment: O que seria o "seletor" correto?

Comment: Algo que identifique o elemento `form` na sua página, tal como o `id`, se ele possuir. É o seletor utilizado pelo jQuery para saber qual elemento na página ele deve tratar.

Comment: Coloquei #Cadastro que é o ID do meu botão de cadastrar. Mas ainda não obtive sucesso. Ao clicar em cadastrar obtenho a mensagem: The value '353.655.450-44' is not valid for CPF. Ou seja, não removeu a máscara.

Comment: O `id` deve ser do **formulário**, não do botão. Algo como `<form id="idDoForm">`.

Comment: Desculpa a pergunta idiota, mas onde fica o ID do form? No Create mesmo?

Comment: Não faço ideia. Como você está exibindo o elemento do formulário no HTML?

Comment: <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:20%; margin-top:10%;">
                            <div class="col-xs-5" style="margin-left:-40px;">
                                <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-success btnNext" id="prox" />
                            </div></div> para o botao cadastrar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58316/discussion-between-felipe-moura-shurrab-and-anderson-carlos-woss).

Comment: Mas e se o campo CPF for numérico, como no meu caso, como eu crio uma máscara num EditFor que já vem de uma model, tipo: model => model.cpf, isso obriga o EditFor só aceitar  números e máscaras não são bem vindas

Comment: @pnet mas por que o CPF seria numérico? Não vejo razão para tal.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, recebi a regra dessa forma(bigint) no banco e long(model-c#)

Comment: @pnet Então recomendo que revise isso com quem lhe deu esta regra. Veja mais em [Tipo do campo CPF ou CNPJ no banco de dados VARCHAR ou INT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/5878) Sem um bom motivo para isso, não há porquê fazer. Na minha resposta, coloquei o trecho referente à receber apenas os dígitos, removendo a máscara; se seu campo é numérico, basta fazer a converção.

Comment: Entendi. Acho que faltou diálogo, mas principalmente entendimento