# Tipo adequado para usar com CPF é numérico ou caractere?

Tags: postgresql, tipagem

Eu tenho um banco de dados com duas tabelas que armazenam o CPF. Numa delas o CPF está armazenado como `numeric(11,0)` e na outra o CPF está armazenado como `character`.

Se é que existe alguma diferença, qual dos dois tipos de dados ocupa mais espaço de armazenamento?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu entendo que um CPF não se trata de um tipo númerico, e sim, de uma string de digitos (Existem CPFs que começam com zeros a esquerda), por isso, uma melhor abstração do dado seria a utilização de um tipo `character varying(11)`.

E mesmo que o tipo `character varying(11)` ocupe mais espaço do que o tipo `numeric(11,0)` e o intento seja "otimizar", ainda sim, não vale a pena substitui-lo. Otimizações dessa natureza quase sempre são "precoces".

Answer (score 12):

O `character` ocupa ligeiramente mais, mas é o correto. CPF é uma informação descritiva que por acaso é composta só de dígitos, um dia pode nem ser assim. Você não precisa fazer cálculos com ele, ele não quantifica nada, então usar um tipo numérico não faz o menor sentido.

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101).

Isto pode ser testando facilmente no banco de dados:

```
SELECT pg_column_size(CHAR(11) '999999999'), pg_column_size(VARCHAR(11) '999999999'), pg_column_size(NUMERIC(9,0) '999999999');
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/70394/5). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/CharVarchar.sql).

Note que o `CHAR` é o que ocupa mais (o que me surpreende, isto parece algo ruim do PostgreSQL), porém é o semanticamente mais correto. Pensa bem, se você sabe que esta informação tem 11 caracteres, porque iria criar um tipo que o tamanho é variável? Em bancos de dados normais este deveria ser o mais econômico já que ele não precisa de nenhum metadado de controle, sei lá porque o PostgreSQL faz isto. Em outro banco de dados pode dar um resultado diferente. Não seria melhor usar uma solução geral?

Curiosamente usar um `VARCHAR` é uma otimização prematura.

Comment: Lendo a documentação e ver quanto cada tipo ocupa.

Comment: Olá, maniero! Obrigado pela sua resposta. Sua resposta e a do Lacobus me ajudaram bastante a entender, no entanto, este último me ajudou com um detalhe sutil, indicando o tipo de dados `character varying`.

Comment: Ah tá! Nem pensei em ler a documentação foi por isso que postei no ptSO. /s

Comment: @TonyMontana Coloquei como medir.

Answer (score -9):

Enquanto CPF não tiver letras, é tipo numérico.

É mais [econômico no armazenamento](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html) e mais [eficiente na indexação](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/137949).

[Zeros à esquerda](https://www.dicionariopopular.com/zero-a-esquerda/), pontos e traços são [competência da interface](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1786/csharp-mascaras-dinamicas-para-textbox-com-qualquer-tipo-numerico-cep-cpf-cnpj-moeda-data.aspx).

Veja o exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b43fc/3).

Comment: A informação sobe eficiência na indexação não é de todo verdadeira.  Dado os [tipos de índices](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html) fornecidos pelo PostgreSQL, é verdade que em colunas indexadas com b-tree oferecem operações de busca bastante flexíveis em indices int8 complexidade de tempo logarítmico contra a complexidade de tempo polilogarítmico em indices char. Porém colunas char indexadas com hashtable oferecem operações de busca com complexidade de tempo constante restritas a busca por igualdade não pode ser aplicado a colunas int8 apenas a int4 que não cabe cpf.

Comment: Zero à esquerda pode não fazer diferença pra valores numéricos, mas pra CPF faz sim: https://economia.uol.com.br/noticias/redacao/2020/04/27/auxilio-r-600-zero-cpf-some-confirmacao-do-pedido.htm

Comment: @AugustoVasques por que alguém indexaria um campo tipo inteiro com hash se indexá-lo com b-tree, como você mesmo apontou, é mais eficiente?

Comment: @hkotsubo como eu disse, zeros à esquerda são competência da camada de apresentação, não da camada de armazenamento. O link que você citou aponta justamente um erro na interface.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47873/101

Comment: @WillyStadnick, Foi o contrário as pessoas indexam com hashtable pois o tempo de busca é *O(1)*, em tipos inteiros indexam até int4 e permitem apenas consultas por igualdade. Enquanto b-tree tempo de busca é *O(log n)* para int em geral e *O(log(n)ᶜ)*  para char, b-trees podem indexam todos os tipos de dados do PostgreSQL onde a perda de desempenho é compensada por pesquisas mais flexíveis.