# Comando sair em string java, mostrar nome e numero apos digitar SAIR

Tags: java

Criar um programa para aceitar a digitação de nome e telefone de uma pessoa, enquanto o nome digitado for diferente de SAIR.
Quando for digitado SAIR, mostrar o nome e telefone da primeira e última pessoa digitada, e a quantidade de nomes digitados.

Estou tendo problemas em tudo que eu faço, se alguem poder ajudar vai ser legal :)

meu código:

```
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package atividade2;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author mojan
 */
public class Atividade2 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String nome;
        int numero;
        String sair;
        int count;

       while(true){ 
        Scanner leia = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite um nome");
        nome = leia.nextLine();        
        System.out.println("Digite um número de telefone");
        numero = leia.nextInt();
        if(nome.equals("sair") || nome.isEmpty());
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um título melhor que descreva qual é a sua dúvida? "ajuda aqui por favor" não diz sobre o que é a pergunta. Aproveite na edição e adicione no corpo da pergunta também uma descrição da sua dúvida. Deu erro? Qual? Não está funcionando de acordo? Quando? Quais entradas colocou? Quais saídas gerou? Quais eram esperadas?

Comment: desculpa, pronto

Comment: "*Estou tendo problemas em tudo que eu faço*"?

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado, mas enfim: telefone não é um número (no sentido de ser um valor numérico que representa uma quantidade ou que dê pra fazer cálculos, etc). Ele é simplesmente uma informação que por acaso usa dígitos (mas que também pode ter letras, sem contar zeros à esquerda, que sumirão se vc converter para número). Leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240764/112052) (apesar de não falar sobre telefone, o problema é o mesmo)

Answer (score 0):

"Estou tendo problemas em tudo", se você direcionar sua dúvida fica mais fácil te ajudar.

Mas teu código tem alguns problemas, o teu break está sendo rodado sempre, independente do retorno do teu if, porque ele está de fora, já que você colou um `;` no final. Removendo o `;` fará com q o teu código só pare caso o if seja true.

Porém você ainda terá outro problema, o teu Scanner vai travar e vai sempre pular o nome a partir da segunda vez, pesquise e descubra o porque, mas pra resolver isso é só no lugar de

```
System.out.println("Digite um número de telefone");
numero = leia.nextInt();
```

você usar

```
System.out.println("Digite um número de telefone");
numero = Integer.valueOf(leia.nextLine());
```

Você recebe uma String, mas passará o valor para o número convertendo para inteiro.

Answer (score 0):

Você também precisa declarar nomes e números como uma lista para poder contar, mostrar a quantidade e também pegar o primeiro valor e último valor digitados, no caso ficaria assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nome;
    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<>();
    final String SAIR = "SAIR";
    Scanner leia = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Digite um nome");
        nome = leia.nextLine();
        if (nome.equalsIgnoreCase(SAIR))
            break;
        nomes.add(nome);
        
        System.out.println("Digite um número de telefone");
        numeros.add(Integer.valueOf(leia.nextLine()));
        
    }
    
    System.out.println("Primeira pessoa digitada: \nNome:" + nomes.get(0) + ", Telefone: " + numeros.get(0));
    System.out.println("Última pessoa digitada: \nNome:" + nomes.get(nomes.size() - 1) + ", Telefone: " + numeros.get(numeros.size() - 1));
    System.out.println("Quantidade de nomes: " + nomes.size());
}
```