# Formatar uma string para formato de telefone

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatação

Tenho a seguinte string `"49988070405"` e quero formata-la para `"(49) 98807-0405"`.

Tentei o código:

```
Convert.ToUInt64("49988070405").ToString(@"\(00\)\ 00000\-0000");
```

Mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
long.Parse("49988070405").ToString(@"(00) 00000-0000"); // (49) 98807-0405
```

Outro exemplo, utilizando extensões:

```
using System;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var phoneString = "49988070405";

        Console.WriteLine(phoneString.FormatPhoneNumber()); // (49) 98807-0405

        var phone = 49988070405;

        Console.WriteLine(phone.FormatPhoneNumber()); // (49) 98807-0405
    }

    public static string FormatPhoneNumber(this long number) {
        return number.ToString(@"(00) 00000-0000");
    }

    public static string FormatPhoneNumber(this string number) {
        return long.Parse(number).FormatPhoneNumber();
    }
}
```

[**Veja os exemplos funcionando no .NET Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Yk5Cb)

Comment: A primeira forma foi suficiente, mas é estranho não haver uma forma mais direta para fazer isso. Primeiro tive que converter a _string_ para _long_, depois para _string_ novamente para poder formatar.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Porque esse é o correto, o que você quer converter é um **número**, e o C# é uma linguagem fortemente tipada, logo não faz sentido nenhum usar uma string para armazena um número. Tem algum motivo para que o número realmente precise ser uma _string_? Pois o correto seria você já tê-lo como _long_.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer o seguinte, segue um exemplo:

```
String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", 8005551212);
```

Que tem como resultado:

```
(800) 555-1212
```

Comment: Mas eu quero o resultado (49) 98807-0405, já tentei esse exemplo ai, não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o seguinte:

```
string phone = "49988070405"
string formatted = string.Format("{0:(##) #####-####}", phone);
```

Answer (score 1):

As respostas não aceitas não funcionam e a aceita tem um erro conceitual convertendo um [dado descritivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101) para número para fazer a formatação, o que é, inclusive, ineficiente.

Você acha que o fato de funcionar sempre fazendo isto não impede o uso? Ok, espero que respeite os conceitos corretos em outras ocasiões que podem não funcionar mais. E espero que ficar ligando e desligando a acurácia conceitual não traga problemas (minha experiência mostra o contrário).

De qualquer forma não tem por que fazer uma conversão só porque parece ser mais simples fazer o código, a formatação deveria ser feita com a forma mais simples ainda, só que não é pronta. Inclusive porque o método [`Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é bem ineficiente.

Também fiz funcionar com números que não são celular. Não me preocupei com números fora do padrão no Brasil porque acho que não existem mais (existia há algum tempo), e não me preocupei com números internacionais. Considerei que é garantido que o número vem sempre correto, caso isto não ocorra tem que verificar e impedir.

Eu não fiz tão simples porque preferi dar o máximo de eficiência usando [`ReadOnlySpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para não alocar no *heap*.

Usei [*ranges*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é um conceito que muitos programadores C# ainda não conhecem, apesar de já ser quase antigo.

```
using static System.Console;
using System;
                    
WriteLine(FormataTelefone("49988070405"));
WriteLine(FormataTelefone("4988070405"));

static string FormataTelefone(string number) {
    if (number.Length != 10 && number.Length != 11) throw new ArgumentException($"Tamanho da string deve ser 10 ou 11", nameof(number));
    ReadOnlySpan<char> span = stackalloc char[number.Length];
    span = number.AsSpan();
    var offset = 11 - number.Length;
    return $"({span[0..2]}) {span[2..(7 - offset)]}-{span[(7 - offset)..]}";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nxj1NZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/FormatPhone.cs).