# Máscara para telefone e celular (8 ou 9 dígitos) no mesmo textbox winforms

Tags: c#

Boa noite, estou com dificuldades para criar uma mascara que aceite tanto numero de celular como numero de telefone no mesmo textbox, tentei usar o maskedinput mais não rolou.. alguma ideia de como poderia fazer? E em qual evento seria melhor para colocar? (keypress, keyup, keydown, leave)

Agradeço desde já a ajuda de todos!

Está ai um trecho do código que fiz até o momento usando o maskedinput..

```
String telefone = Useful_methods.TextNoFormatting(txtTelefone_1);
if (telefone.Length >= 10)
{
   txtTelefone_1.Mask = "(00)00000-0000";
   txtTelefone_1.Select(txtTelefone_1.Text.Length, 1);
}
else
{
   txtTelefone_1.Mask = "(00)0000-00009";
}
```

Comment: Pretende que o formato seja validado enquanto o utilizador introduz o número ou pode ser no evento de `LostFocus`?

Comment: pode ser no LostFocus

Comment: Veja as respostas já dadas antes para aprender fazer a forma correta, e não apenas que funcione: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/283609/101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se pretender aplicar a máscara apenas quando o `focus` sair do controlo, pode evocar este método:

```
string AplicarMascaraTelefone(string strNumero)
{
    // por omissão tem 10 ou menos dígitos
    string strMascara = "{0:(00)0000-0000}";
    // converter o texto em número
    long lngNumero = Convert.ToInt64(strNumero);

    if (strNumero.Length == 11)
        strMascara = "{0:(00)00000-0000}";

    return string.Format(strMascara, lngNumero);
}
```

Vai devolver a string já formatada para aplicar na sua `TextBox`.