# ERROR 1264: 1264: Out of range value for column 'cpf' at row 1 SQL Statement

Tags: mysql

Estou com um problema no MySQL, criei a seguinte Tabela:

```
create table pessoas (
cpf int (11),
nome varchar(30) not null,
nascimento date,
endereco varchar(30) not null,
cep int(7),
bairro varchar(20),
cidade varchar(30),
uf char (2),
primary key(cpf)
)default charset = utf8;
```

Adicionei uma coluna:

```
alter table pessoas
add column ultima_compra date;
```

fui tentar fazer o seguinte insert:

```
insert into pessoas values
('04496332780', 'João da Silva', '25-11-1969', 'Rua Antônio Numes', '88045963', 'Palmeiras','Londrina', 'PR');
```

E deu esse erro:

> ERROR 1264: 1264: Out of range value for column 'cpf' at row 1
>   SQL Statement:**

Comment: cpf deve ser um varchar e não um int. Estourou a capacidade do int diz o erro.

Comment: Mais em: [Tipo do campo CPF ou CNPJ no banco de dados VARCHAR ou INT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/91)

Answer (score -3):

O seu erro foi criar colunas como Int e tentar gravar varchar.
Tente retirando aspas de cpf e cep:

```
insert into pessoas values (04496332780, 'João da Silva', '25-11-1969', 'Rua Antônio Numes', 88045963, 'Palmeiras','Londrina', 'PR');
```

*Editando (realmente não reparei que excedia 10 dígitos):
int aceita até 10 dígitos. Crie a tabela usando o tipo correto:

```
bigint: -9.223.372.036.854.775.808 à 9.223.372.036.854.775.807
int:    -2.147.483.648 a 2.147.483.647
smallint    -32,768 a 32,767
```

Comment: Mesmo com as aspas o banco tentaria fazer a conversão implicitamente para o tipo devido. O problema é a capacidade do tipo numérico como o @rray já sinalizou.

Comment: Mas o tipo correto para CPF não é numérico!

Comment: Não estou aqui dizendo o que ele deve fazer ou não. Essa não foi a pergunta dele. A pergunta dele foi o que seria aquele erro. E acredito que tenha respondido.

Comment: Eu descobrir esse erro o que era, o tamanho do campo cep estava com o tamanho menor. alterei o tamanho porem agora estou com outro problema.

Comment: Qual seria? Poste o erro aqui