# Não estou conseguindo cadastrar o nome de uma pessoas na minha agenda

Tags: c, array, struct

Estou fazendo uma agenda bem simples, os números eu consegui castrar porém os nomes das pessoas eu não consegui.

Meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define MAX 50

typedef struct
{
  int numero[MAX];
  char nome[MAX];
  int tam;

} AGENDA;

void imprime(AGENDA *L);
void cadastrar(AGENDA *lista);
void inicia(AGENDA *lista);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  AGENDA *agenda = (AGENDA*)malloc(sizeof(AGENDA) * MAX);
  int op;
  do
  {
     printf("1-adicionar numero\n");
     printf("2-remover numero\n");
     printf("3-procurar numero\n");
     printf("4-Imprimir\n");
     printf("6-incia-a-agenda\n");
     printf("7-Parar\n");
     scanf("%d", &op);
     switch(op)
     {
     case 1:
         cadastrar(agenda);
         break;
     case 6:
         inicia(agenda);
         break;
     case 4:
         imprime(agenda);
         break;
    }
 }
  while(op != 7);
   free(agenda);
   return 0;
 }
void cadastrar(AGENDA *lista)
{
 int op;
 do
 {
    printf("Digite o numero\n");
    scanf("%d", &lista->numero[lista->tam]);
    printf("Digite o seu nome\n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", lista->nome[lista->tam]);
    printf("Digite 1 para continuar 2 para parar\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    lista->tam++;
 }
 while(op != 2);
}

void imprime(AGENDA *L)
{
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < L->tam; i++)
 {
    printf("%d\n", L->numero[i]);
    printf("%s\n", L->nome[i]);
 }
}

void inicia(AGENDA *lista)
{
  lista->tam = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está em como você estruturou os dados na estrutura. `nome` deve ser uma matriz, e não um vetor. Fazendo:

```
typedef struct
{
  int numero[MAX];
  char nome[MAX][MAX];
  int tam;

} AGENDA;
```

No seu código atualmente, você está tentando salvar uma string em um char, o que não é possível. Como você quer utilizar várias strings, o que você deve fazer é utilizar uma matriz de caracteres.

Um comentário extra que gostaria de fazer é que, particularmente, eu atacaria o problema de outra forma. Ao invés de fazer o struct guardar todos os contatos, fazer com que cada struct guarde um contato e a partir daí fazer um vetor de Contatos. Logo, a estrutura se tornaria:

```
typedef struct {
  int numero;
  char nome[MAX];
} Contato;
```

Comment: Obrigado, só mais uma dúvida nessa parte eu aloquei AGENDA *agenda = (AGENDA*)malloc(sizeof(AGENDA) * MAX); a struct, não era para ter criado a matriz de String ?

Comment: Não, a única coisa que você fez foi criar várias AGENDA. No seu caso, é como se você estivesse salvando todos os contatos dentro de uma única variável do tipo AGENDA pelo que eu entendi. Por isso sugeri a ideia de criar a estrutura Contato e depois criar um vetor de contatos, usando malloc mesmo: `Contato *agenda = malloc (MAX * sizeof(Contato))`

Comment: Entedi Obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 5):

Reescrevi o código para mostrar mais ou menos como se faz. Note que ainda tem muito o melhorar nele. Tem erros que podem acontecer facilmente e estão estão sendo verificados, fora outros detalhes, mas assim é como se faz de verdade, mesmo algo simples.

Colocar vários *arrays* dentro da `struct` não faz sentido algum, o que deseja é mais simples e mais viável que isto. Sua `struct` de agenda deve ter apenas o tamanho e um ponteiro para a lista de contatos. Isto já é conceitualmente correto e facilita fazer o resto.

Criei uma nova estrutura com a entrada do contato. Se quiser pode chamar de contato, mas não sei se é adequado em um contexto real. Nela terá o número e o nome. O número eu mudei para *string* porque geralmente é o número do telefone, então o [`int` não é adequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101). Se for outra coisa, aí parece fazer menos sentido ainda deixar a pessoa digitar isto.

Predeterminei que o nome terá 30 caracteres, você pode usar o tamanho que quiser.

Controlei melhor a digitação. Tem falhas em usar o `scanf()` assim, mas para um exercício está bom.

Veja que dei um nome melhor para a função que inicializa a agenda, para ficar claro que precisa liberá-la. E criei antes de qualquer forma, até para evitar outro erro. E mudei a inicialização para reinicialização. Tem um erro aí na reinicialização, que de certa forma eu introduzi, veja se consegue identificar e arrumar, assim exercita de verdade.

Se não entender algum ponto faça perguntas específicas.

Fiz outras simplificações e melhoria. Já que quer aprender preste atenção a cada detalhe, até nos espaços. Tinha outros errado que corrigi, fica de exercício identificá-los.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define MAX 50

typedef struct {
    char numero[12]; //permite um telefone nacional
    char nome[31]; //permite 30 caracteres
} Entrada;

typedef struct {
    int tamanho;
    Entrada *contatos;
} Agenda; 
    
void cadastrar(Agenda *agenda) {
    int op = 1;
    do {
        printf("Digite o telefone\n");
        scanf("%11s", agenda->contatos[agenda->tamanho].numero);
        printf("Digite o seu nome\n");
        scanf(" %30[^\n]", agenda->contatos[agenda->tamanho].nome);
        printf("Digite 1 para continuar 2 para parar\n");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        agenda->tamanho++;
    } while (op != 2);
}

void imprime(Agenda agenda) {
    for (int i = 0; i < agenda.tamanho; i++) printf("%11s - %s\n", agenda.contatos[i].numero, agenda.contatos[i].nome);
}

Agenda iniciaAlocaAgenda() {
    return (Agenda) { .tamanho = 0, .contatos = malloc(sizeof(Entrada) * MAX) };

}

void liberaAgenda(Agenda agenda) {
    free(agenda.contatos);
}


int main() {
    Agenda agenda = iniciaAlocaAgenda();
    int op = 1;
    do {
        printf("1-Adicionar numero\n");
        printf("2-Remover numero\n");
        printf("3-Procurar numero\n");
        printf("4-Imprimir\n");
        printf("6-Reincia a agenda\n");
        printf("7-Parar\n");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        switch (op) {
        case 1:
            cadastrar(&agenda);
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            imprime(agenda);
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            agenda = iniciaAlocaAgenda();
            break;
        }
    } while (op != 7);
    liberaAgenda(agenda);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yquuhN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/feslkivk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/ArrayStructAbstraction.c).