# Valor colocado no "define()" não é apresentado corretamente

Tags: php, formatação, números

Bem pessoal, estou escrevendo um sistema de "versionamento", tenho uma classe que coleta e compara algumas informações. Na *index* do meu projeto eu passo a versão atual do sistema e no arquivo de configuração eu defino a chave da versão.

```
public function getEncodeVersion()
{
    return "0x".strtoupper(dechex(crc32($this->version)));
}
```

Essa função coleta a versão atual.

No meu arquivo de definição, eu tenho o seguinte `define()`:

```
define("updateKeyReview", 0x133B6236);  //sem Aspas
```

Eu recupero e comparo esse valor nesta função

```
public function compareVersion()
{
    if(constant("updateKeyReview") != $this->getEncodeVersion())
        $this->getMessageUpdate();
}
```

Na teoria deveria funcionar perfeitamente, porque é apenas uma comparação boba, porém obtive a mensagem de versão atualizada, até eu dar um `echo` no meu `define()`, ao invés dele retornar o valor que estou passando nele que é ***0x133B6236***, ele está retornando ***322658870***, como se tivesse convertendo o valor que eu pego no `define()`, porém se eu coloco assim:

```
define("updateKeyReview", "0x133B6236"); //com Aspas
```

Ele funciona normalmente, eu já sei que está funcionando dessa forma, eu só queria entender o que acontece e porquê o valor é convertido.

Comment: O *PHP* interpreta o valor `0x133B6236` (sem aspas) como um código hexadecimal, por isso ele está convertendo o valor. Com a utilização das aspas, você deixa explícito que o valor é uma *string* e que o *PHP* não deverá convertê-lo.

Comment: Compreendo Valdeir e agradeço pelo comentário.
Porém, na versão 5.6 do PHP não tenho esse problema, e lendo o patch notes do PHP, não vi mudança na função DEFINE, que traria o resultado atual.
Mesmo assim, agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Isso não ocorre causa da função `define`. Se você executar o código `echo 0x133B6236;`, a saída será *322658870*. Para o *PHP*, todo o valor iniciado por `0x` ou `0X` (e que esteja sem aspas) é considerado um código hexadecimal e por isso ele é interpretado e convertido. https://ideone.com/Q4XZ6O

Comment: Teste noutras versões do PHP: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6599b0929bd2f9288353b4c9034e07e64e25be86

Comment: Realmente, eu testei e o resultado foi o mesmo em todas as versões.
Porem eu já utilizei dessa forma que fiz anteriormente e não tive erro.
Mesmo assim, muito obrigado e valew pela atenção.

Comment: @WagnerCorrêaRosa A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

## O que são números

Existe uma coisa que é o número, algo contável, algo que existe na natureza, e portanto existe no computador através de eletricidade, e existe uma representação numérica que nós humanos criamos para facilitar nosso entendimento, até porque não lidamos bem com o que não vemos. Portanto criamos uma representação textual para números, criamos o tal do 0, 1, 2, etc. que tanto lidamos todos os dias, e nem nos damos conta que são apenas textos (que são só desenhos) que entendemos como números.

No computador quando vemos número na tela é só um texto, sempre. Nunca é um número, especialmente na sintaxe da linguagem quando escrevemos um código. E não importa se está ali em notação decimal, hexadecimal, binária ou outra, são só representações textuais.

Porém há uma diferença de sintaxe que usamos para dizer quando queremos que aquilo seja tratado como número e quando queremos que seja tratado como texto. Ficou convencionado que se escrevermos uma sequência de algarismos numéricos de forma simples é um número e o computador tratará assim, ele poderá fazer cálculos com aquilo. Em algumas linguagens também convencionou-se que é possível usar uma notação diferente de decimal, por exemplo se tiver um prefixo `0x` significa que ele será hexadecimal, e até por isso algumas letras poderão ser usadas no número.

Se você quiser imprimir esse número na tela será incompreensível de forma direta, ele é representado no computador de forma que o ser humano não entende, e mesmo uma conversão direta para texto aparecerá algo muito estranho. A solução é fazer contas para transformar esse número em caracteres que representem esse número de forma que o ser humano entende. Como existe uma função pronta que lidar com isso nem paramos para pensar que essa conversão está ocorrendo. E novamente, não importa se a representação é decimal ou não, cada um escolhe como quer, apenas o padrão é decimal.

Quando colocamos um número entre aspas ele é só um texto que por acaso só tem algarismos numéricos, nada mais. Não pode calcular com ele, para o computador ele não é um número de fato, só uma sequência de caracteres (na verdade indo mais a fundo é uma sequência de números que são usados através de uma tabela de caracteres desenhados.

Então se usar um número e quiser escrever um texto de forma direta na teoria e na prática funcionará por causa de tudo o que escrevi, e em decimal ninguém percebe qualquer problema. Em hexadecimal dá para perceber um problema porque o padrão é escrever em decimal, então o que você escreveu em código hexadecimal não será respeitado, a não ser que peça para escrever em formato hexadecimal.

Reforço: decimal ou hexadecimal são só duas formas diferentes de representar textualmente um **número**.

Então você precisa decidir se isso é uma descrição, se for deve usar um texto, assim como [CPF e telefone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101) que parecem ser números mas são textos. Ou se é um número, que precisa fazer cálculo. Se for o primeiro fica fácil e tudo funciona, se for o segundo tem que tomar o cuidado de mandar imprimir em notação hexadecimal, se é o que deseja, aí funciona.

Você tem que, em primeiro lugar, conceituar certo o que está fazendo.

## `define()`

O problema não é do `define()` e duvido que tenha diferença entre as versões do PHP, se tiver, apresente indícios disso, vai acabar descobrindo que algum erro ocorreu entre uma e outra versão.