# Error unknown type name 'tipoTelefone'

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    int id;
    char nome[20];
    tipoTelefone telefone;
}tipoCliente;

typedef struct{
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int x3;
    int x4;
    char digito;
    int y1;
    int y2;
    int y3;
    int y4;
}tipoTelefone;

int main(){
    int n,q,i,j,cont;
    char teste;
    printf("Qtds:\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&q);

    tipoCliente cliente[n];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d %s %d%d%d%d%s%d%d%d%d",&cliente[i].id,&cliente[i].nome,&cliente[i].telefone.x1,&cliente[i].telefone.x2,&cliente[i].telefone.x3,&cliente[i].telefone.x4,&cliente[i].telefone.digito,&cliente[i].telefone.y1,&cliente[i].telefone.y2,&cliente[i].telefone.y3,&cliente[i].telefone.y4);
    }

//  for(j = 0; j < q; j++){
//      scanf("%d",&q_id);
//  }
//  
//  for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
//      if(strcmp(cliente[i].nome,cliente[i + 1].nome) < 0){
//          
//      }else if(strcmp(cliente[i].nome,cliente[i + 1].nome) == 0){
//          if(cliente[i].id > cliente[i + 1].id){
//              
//          }
//      }
//  }

    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d %s %d%d%d%d%s%d%d%d%d",cliente[i].id,cliente[i].nome,cliente[i].telefone.x1,cliente[i].telefone.x2,cliente[i].telefone.x3,cliente[i].telefone.x4,cliente[i].telefone.digito,cliente[i].telefone.y1,cliente[i].telefone.y2,cliente[i].telefone.y3,cliente[i].telefone.y4);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Erro apresentado ao compilar o código]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está usando um tipo criado depois do seu uso, neste ponto o compilador anida não sabe que você vai criar lá na frente, precisa colocar as declarações na ordem certa, então declarar o `tipoTelefone` antes resolverá este problema.

Este tipo parece muito esquisito, no mínimo deveria mudar `int` para `char` para ocupar menos espaço. Eu ainda faria de outra forma usando uma *string*.

Comment: Eu fiz pois não consigo pensar em uma maneira de receber um número de telefone no formato xxxx-yyyy e com esse número de telefone, fazer a seguinte soma: xxxx+yyyy. Se tiver uma dica, eu agradeceria. De qualquer forma, já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Não consigo imaginar porque faria esta soma. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101.

Comment: Para adequar aos critérios de um programa que eu estou fazendo. O critério é que para cada cliente, calcula-se a soma xxxx + yyyy. Em seguida, calcula-se o resto desta soma na divisão por 7, ou seja, o valor do resultado é um número entre 0 e 6. O cliente que tiver o menor valor deve ser chamado primeiro

Comment: Nossa, isso é requisito maluco, de qualquer forma tem melhores jeitos de construir isto, mas aí já é outro assunto que nem quero me mter.

Comment: Coisas de faculdade, cara. De qualquer forma, você já ajudou muito com o erro da struct. Obrigado!

Comment: pelo menos troque o tipo `int` pra `char` pra economizar espaço.