# Seria má pratica inserir símbolos monetários direto no banco?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, tipagem, valor-monetário

Em um sistema tive que mexer em valores de salários e comissões, realizar cálculos sobre eles e afins. Porém fui analisar que está sendo inserido os símbolos monetários direto no Banco de dados, sendo uma *string*, e inserindo os valores junto com uma máscara do JQuery.

```
Value:    R$  20
```

Tive que transformar esses valores de *strings* para *float* removendo o símbolo monetário utilizando o comando `str_replace()` do PHP.

```
$value = (float)str_replace('R$  ','', $value);
```

Porém estou com duvida se seria certo utilizar esta prática. Seria melhor criar outro atributo/coluna no banco de dados com um nome `simboloMonetario` e mudar o valor de *string* para *double*?

Comment: Usar `float` para coisas que não sejam cálculos científicos já é um problema, na verdade. Não conheço o tipo adequado do PHP, mas o `Decimal` do C# ou o `BigDecimal` do Java fazem o trabalho corretamente, sem perder precisão. Além disso, a informação que você deseja guardar no banco dificilmente é a string de exibição, porém o valor dela. Se for guardada a string de exibição, eu não consigo, por exemplo, somar os valores da coluna de maneira eficientemente

Comment: A melhor prática seria você ter um campo a parte identificando a moeda na qual está expresso o valor.

Comment: Com certeza complica trabalhar com strings se você for usar estes campos para calculos, não concorda? Por exemplo quer ver o valor de entrada e saída de um ano especifico, teria que somar, imagine somar strings e ainda com símbolos. Claro que posso citar outros problemas, mas isso é só para ter a ideia principal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esta pergunta é o oposto da: [Tipo do campo CPF ou CNPJ no banco de dados VARCHAR ou INT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101).

Naquela a pessoa queria colocar dados descritivos como se fossem quantidade e estava errado. Agora esta pergunta quer colocar quantidades como dados descritivos, o que também está errado. Não é questão de boa ou má prática, é errado, e isto que importa. Você pode fazer e pode até funcionar, mas é errado. Valores monetários são quantidades e devem ser guardados como números e o tipo correto para ele é o `DECIMAL` (pode usar um inteiro se souber o que está fazendo e quiser ter o trabalho de lidar com isso), não use outros tipos que não possuem exatidão. Um tipo texto garantiria a exatidão, mas criaria inúmeros problemas, por exemplo, como somaria estes valores?

Note que no PHP você também pode ter problemas, porque por padrão o PHP trabalha com valores com parte decimal sem exatidão (a maioria dos sistemas em PHP e de outras linguagens que rodam por aí estão errados e os programadores nem sabem disto porque [usam `float` como se eles fossem exatos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101), veja mais em [valor-monetário](/questions/tagged/valor-monet%c3%a1rio)).

Se está gravando assim sem querer eu me preocuparia mais ainda, você deve estar no controle de tudo o que ocorre, e claramente está ocorrendo algo ruim. Sempre que precisa dessas conversões, limpezas, troca de símbolos está fazendo algo errado, essas coisas são necessárias para consertar o erro inicial, então conserte ele e não precisará dessas coisas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: e o uso de double para os valores monetários, poderia complementar sua resposta com isso? grato!

Comment: @EliseuB. editei.

Comment: havia dado erro mesmo ao converter do banco de dados, tirar o valor monetário, e depois transformar para float, o valor era 1000 e acabou sendo transformado para 1. Isso seria problema de precisão?

Comment: Não, isso é erro de programação mesmo, e eu não falei nada de precisão na minha resposta.

Comment: Acabei me confundindo com exatidão. Muito obrigado pela resposta.