# Como modelar tempo em banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mariadb, time

Basicamente eu preciso criar um CRUD pra gerenciar álbuns e faixas de música. Na tabela de faixas, tem um campo para o tempo de duração da música. Qual tipo do MySQL eu poderia usar pra guardar esse tipo de informação?

Comment: Você precisa armazenar a string com a informação. Há diversas formas de fazer isso. Especifique o que pretende fazer com o dado. É apenas informativo, é para calcular tempo reverso, somar e informar a playlist?

Comment: Creio que a convenção é algo do tipo Qwert Yuiop XX:XX , poderia se gravar como CHAR e um campo calculado Number informar isto em segundos , não sei para que seria usado mas isto permite exibir e calcular tempos (somados) , algumas faixas como de clássico podem somar horas , também não sei se é o caso. Sendo só informativo eu usaria CHAR.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Depende do que deseja fazer com esse tempo. Nunca é tão simples e universal escolher algo sem todas as informações.

Se tiver certeza que o dado é [só descritivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101) e nunca mudará deve ser uma *string*, e o tipo exato depende do banco de dados. Um `VARCHAR` parece bem bom no MySQL, ainda que um `CHAR` pode ser interessante também, mas nem tanto (contra intuitivamente ele pode ser pior). Mas o `CHAR` pode ser claramente a melhor opção, ou até um `NCHAR`(não tem no MySQL). Se for usar um `CHAR` tem que tomar cuidado porque o tempo máximo pode ser bem maior do que espera. Pode ser que tenha horas, ou até dias (mesmo que não queira destacar desta forma ainda pode ter dígitos demais), o que já tende indicar um `VARCHAR` como opção mais interessante. Mais ainda pode ser mais complicado.

Se pode ter durações de faixas muito grandes pode ser melhor não deixar algo descritivo, e pode até nem poder ser assim por outras razões, aí um tipo numérico pode ser mais interessante. Um `INT` provavelmente é a melhor opção onde guardaria os segundos de duração. A apresentação do número em forma de tempo que humanos costumam entender ficaria a cargo da aplicação, assim como a entrada para converter em segundos também. Pode precisar algo que permita número maiores.

Cuidado para não usar um tipo que parece que marca quantidade tempo quando na verdade guarda um ponto na linha do tempo que é algo totalmente diferente. Esqueça `TIME` ou `TIMESTAMP`, mais ainda outros que tem algum tempo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Na descrição do desafio não deixa muito claro o uso desse campo, mas tenho certeza que é um dado apenas para deixar o exemplo mais "realista" mesmo. Usarei um tipo numérico pra guardar os segundos e dar um jeito de converter e formatar depois, só pra deixar o site do desafio mais "dinâmico"