# Qual o tipo correto para se armazenar telefone e endereço?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tipagem

Como o título diz, qual o tipo correto e a maneira correta para se armazenar telefone e endereço, **de acordo com a normalização de banco de dados**?

- No caso de telefone, qual o tipo correto para armazenar, o telefone fixo e celular? Com máscara de formatação ou não?
- E no caso de endereço, como armazená-lo? Em vários outros campos, como rua, bairro, número e cidade, ou tudo em um/dois somente?

Comment: [Tipos de dados para colunas específicas para base de dados SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4170/91)

Answer (score 0):

No caso de **telefone**, qual o tipo correto para armazenar, o telefone fixo e celular? Com máscara de formatação ou não?

Varia de programador para programador, mas no meu caso eu faço sempre com mascara de formatação para deixar mais fácil para ler os dados ou ate mesmo retornar ele. Sobre o armazenamento eu geralmente crio Duas `tabelas` uma para fixo e outra para cel e utilizo a `chave estrangeira` do usuario para poder linkar.

E no caso de endereço, como armazená-lo? Em vários outros campos, como rua, bairro, número e cidade, ou tudo em um/dois somente?

Para este aqui eu gosto de fazer a seguinte arquitetura

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que eu vou desmembrando cada campo do endereço em uma tabela. E na hora de juntar tudo utilizo um `inner join`.

obs.: utilizei um exemplo claro que você pode colocar até CEP, complemento etc.

Comment: Achei interessante a forma como fez, mas desta forma há a necessidade de prévio cadastro dos Estados, Cidades e Bairros para conseguir criar um endereço. Isto lhe gera alguma crítica do usuário? Como contornou a questão destes prévios cadastros? Estou tentando imaginar a usabilidade do frontend, onde vejo que temos que ter a maior facilidade possível.

Comment: Então a melhor coisa pelo menos é pegar um base da dados de todas as cidades e estados pelo menos pois você não vai fazer com que o Usuário digite algo que não cabe em um dos campos e faz com que não tenha duplicidade de campos (Ex. Campinas , CPS , campinas).
Sobre a aceitação para o usuario é normal já que alguns tempos atrás era feito assim o cadastro de compras das lojas americanas.
Uma ideia já que esta fazendo Web existe algumas API's que ao colocar o  CEP ele já preenche os campos mais importantes para o Usuário. 
Se você saber mexer com API's vai ser facil fazer isto.