# Preciso criar uma classe "assinatura" em meu diagrama de classes

Tags: diagrama

Estou fazendo um diagrama de classes de um sistema que ira localizar, intermediar compra e agendamentos de serviços de petshops, o cliente terá uma opção de ter uma assinatura básica ou premium (onde o mesmo terá descontos a mais),porem não estou conseguindo desenvolver uma classe assinatura, além disso, preciso de uma classe "faturamento" onde vai se contabilizar os lucros que o sistema terá. [image: Diagrama de classes v.03]

Comment: Não entendi qual é exatamente a dúvida ou pergunta. Qual foi a dificuldade?

Comment: Não acho uma boa idéia usar int para CPF, CNPJ e CEP! Dá  uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4170/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-tipos-de-dados-apropriados-para-colunas-como-endere%C3%A7o-e-mail-tele