# Palavras correspondentes a números de telefones

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinações

Seja a tabela de correspondência abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Escreva um script que, dado um número de sete dígitos, gere todas as combinações possíveis de palavras de sete letras correspondentes a esse número. Existem 2.187 (3<sup>7</sup>) dessas combinações. Evite números de telefone com dígitos 0 e 1 (para os quais nenhuma letra corresponde).

A minha tentativa:

```
import itertools

letters = ['   ', '   ', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PRS', 'TUV', 'WXY']


telefone = 2345678

total = ''
for i in str(telefone):
    total += letters[int(i)]

anagramas = []
for anagrama in itertools.combinations(total, len(str(telefone))):
    anagramas.append(''.join(anagrama))

print(anagramas)
```

Mas são geradas MUITO mais combinações do que o problema quer. Alguma ideia?

Esta questão é do livro de Python do Deitel.

Comment: Ao menos defina TODO o problema.

Comment: @hkotsubo   Completei a pergunta.

Comment: @Motta Completei a pergunta.

Comment: Desculpem:  Eu acabei na hora de editar apagando parte do enunciado!

Comment: Creio que os "for" deveriam estar encadeados , um for dentro do outro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você cria uma string contendo todas as letras correspondentes aos dígitos do telefone, e depois gera todas as combinações possíveis desta string.

Ou seja, muitas dessas combinações terão o primeiro caractere correspondente a um dígito que não é o primeiro do telefone. E o mesmo vale para todos os dígitos em todas as posições.

Então na verdade o que você quer é gerar o produto cartesiano das letras. No módulo `itertools` basta usar a função `product`, passando como primeiro argumento as letras que correspondem ao primeiro dígito, no segundo argumento as letras que correspondem ao segundo dígito e assim por diante:

```py
import itertools
 
# retorna as letras correspondentes a cada um dos dígitos
def get_letters(fone, letters):
    for i in str(fone):
        yield letters[int(i)]
 
letters = ['0', '1', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PRS', 'TUV', 'WXY']
 
fone = 2345678

for p in itertools.product(*get_letters(fone, letters)):
  print (''.join(p))
```

No caso, `get_letters` é uma função geradora que retorna as letras correspondentes a cada um dos dígitos do telefone (ela não valida se o dígito possui correspondente na lista `letras`, mas pode incluir se for o caso).

Ao chamar `product`, eu uso o asterisco para fazer o [*unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) dos argumentos, ou seja, a primeira string retornada será o primeiro argumento, a segunda string retornada será o segundo argumento, etc.

Por exemplo, se o telefone for "23", a função retorna as strings "ABC" e "DEF", então seria o mesmo que chamar `product("ABC", "DEF")`.

Repare também que incluí strings para os dígitos zero e um (no caso, são os próprios dígitos), assim ele também funciona para telefones que tenham estes dígitos (no caso, eles não são substituídos por letras).

Mas claro que você pode modificar a função para rejeitar determinados dígitos, ou números com a quantidade de dígitos diferente de sete, ou qualquer outra regra que você quiser. Mas independente disso, a lógica para gerar todos os valores possíveis continua a mesma.

---

O código acima só imprime os resultados. Mas se quiser uma lista contendo todos, basta fazer:

```py
result = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(*get_letters(fone, letters))]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Lembrando que [tipos numéricos não são os mais adequados para armazenar números telefônicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4170/137387).

Como já explicado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/532650/137387) o que foi pedido no seu exercício foi que fizesse o [produto cartesiano](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_cartesiano) a partir da transliteração dos dígitos dum número telefônico segundo uma tabela dada.

Como informação disponibilizadas:

- Em Python produto cartesiano pode ser realizado com a função [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).
- A função nativa [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#map) devolve um iterador que aplica função para cada item de um iterável.
- O operator [**(unpacking)*](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) explode um iterável em seus elementos.

Dispondo dessas informações é possível elencar os passos elementáres para solucionar o exercício:

1. Converter o telefone numa string
2. A partir dessa string obter um iterável onde cada elemento é um dígito do telefone convertido segundo a tabela apresentada no exercício.
3. Realizar o produto cartesiano sobre os elementos do iterável obtido.
4. Dispor os resultados em conformidade ao que foi exigido.

```python
from itertools import product

letters = ['0', '1', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PRS', 'TUV', 'WXY']
fone = 2345678  

#Converte o fone numa string e a partir dessa string obtém um iterador para um anagrama  
#relacionando cada dígito de fone a um elemento de letters. 
#Nesse exemplo: ("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PRS", "TUV")
anagrama = map(lambda d: letters[int(d)], str(fone))

#Faz o produto cartesiano entre as string do anagrama obtendo um iterador de tuplas caracteres contendo as combinações buscadas. 
#Exemplo de uma das tuplas escolhidas aleatoriamente: ('C', 'F', 'I', 'K', 'M', 'S', 'T').
#Junta cada uma das tuplas obtidas em uma string e as coloca em uma lista.
resultados = [*map(''.join, product(*anagrama))]

#Imprime os resultados.
print(*resultados, sep="\n")
print(f'Resultados obtidos: {len(resultados)} combinações')
```

resultando em:

```
ADGJMPT
ADGJMPU
ADGJMPV
ADGJMRT
ADGJMRU
ADGJMRV
ADGJMST
ADGJMSU
ADGJMSV
ADGJNPT
...
...
...
CFILORT
CFILORU
CFILORV
CFILOST
CFILOSU
CFILOSV
Resultados obtidos: 2187 combinações
```

<sup>teste o exemplo no [ide.one](https://ideone.com/TduPTN)</sup>

O mesmo algoritmo acima usando [compreensão de lista](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```python
from itertools import product
 
letters = ['0', '1', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PRS', 'TUV', 'WXY']
fone = 2345678
 
anagrama = ((lambda d: letters[int(d)])(d) for d in str(fone))
 
resultados = [''.join(p) for p in product(*anagrama)]
 
print(*resultados, sep="\n")
print(f'Resultados obtidos: {len(resultados)} combinações')
```

<sup>Teste o código no [ide.one](https://ideone.com/SyoGIJ)</sup>

Ainda o mesmo algoritmo usando a pacote [nympy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html). O código usa a função [numpy.meshgrid()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) para obter o produto cartesiano:

```
import numpy as np

letters = ['0', '1', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PRS', 'TUV', 'WXY']
fone = 2345678

anagrama =[np.array(p) for p in ((lambda d: [*letters[int(d)]] )(d) for d in str(fone))]

resultados = [''.join(s) for s in np.array(np.meshgrid(*anagrama)).T.reshape(-1,len(anagrama))]

print(*resultados, sep="\n")
print(f'Resultados obtidos: {len(resultados)} combinações')
```

<sup>Teste o código no [ide.one](https://ideone.com/0r1Ipg)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou muito